# Como fazer uma busca ignorando acentuação em Python?

Tags: python, array, algoritmo-de-busca, acentuação

Suponha que eu tenha uma lista de palavras, em Python (se necessário, já ordenada conforme as regras de *collation*):

```py
palavras = [
    u"acentuacao",
    u"divagacão",
    u"programaçao",
    u"taxação",
]
```

Repare que não usei o cedilha (`ç`) nem o til (`ã`) de forma consistente. Como posso buscar nessa lista por "programação", mas ignorando a acentuação, de modo que várias modalidades de buscas retornem resultados? Ex.:

```py
buscar(palavras, u"programacao")
buscar(palavras, u"programação")
```

Procurei no Google por "collation search" e não encontrei nada de útil. Procurei também por "busca ignorando acentos", de diversas formas, e até encontrei [uma solução para MySQL](http://www.compilando.org/outros/busca-sql-ignorando-acentuacao-mysql) (que confirma que o caminho certo é mesmo via *collate*), mas nada para Python (apenas referências para [como ordenar uma lista](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1097908/520779), o que por si só não responde à pergunta). O módulo [`locale`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html) também não ofereceu grande ajuda. Como fazer?

Comment: Em inglês: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/

Comment: @bfavaretto abordagem interessante, não tinha pensado nisso (normalizar e remover diacríticos). Pena que isso envolveria modificar o array original (embora na prática, em muitos casos isso não seria problema).

Comment: É uma abordagem que já vi ser muito usada em outras linguagens (ex: js, php). Infelizmente meus conhecimentos de python são bem superficiais, então não arrisco postar uma resposta.

Comment: @bfavaretto Se quiser tentar, eu te ajudo... :P Caso contrário, eu mesmo vou postar uma resposta mais tarde. Estava investigando se seria possível fazer isso via busca binária e `strcoll`, mas sem resultado... Vou tentar criar uma prova-de-conceito usando sua sugestão, mas se quiser dar uma resposta parcial, pra mim está de bom tamanho.

Comment: Vá em frente e poste a sua. Quem sabe quando eu estudar python (não acho tempo!) consigo postar uma melhor que a sua :)

Comment: Se fosse em C#, poderia mandar para a equipe do SE: http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/449/permitir-buscas-ignorando-acentuacao :P

Comment: @bigown hehe foi aquela pergunta no meta que me inspirou a postar essa aqui... :P

Comment: @bigown No caso do SOPT é relativamente simples, basta usar COLLATE na query. Resolveria aqui, mas não para qualquer site localizado - a colação precisaria ser parametrizada.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Com base no comentário e [referência](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/) do @bfavaretto, consegui montar uma prova-de-conceito. A solução é remover os diacríticos tanto da lista a ser buscada quanto do termo de busca. Para isso, primeiro se normaliza a string de modo a garantir que os caracteres combinantes estejam representados separado, depois se remove esses caracteres (que no caso dos acentos, cedilha etc, possuem a categoria Unicode [`Mn`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Mn/list.htm)).

Tentei fazer a substituição usando o módulo [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex), sem sucesso, então optei por uma função separada. O código da busca [binária] veio [dessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2233940/520779) no SO em inglês.

```py
import unicodedata
from bisect import bisect_left

def remover_combinantes(string):
    string = unicodedata.normalize('NFD', string)
    return u''.join(ch for ch in string if unicodedata.category(ch) != 'Mn')

palavras_norm = [remover_combinantes(x) for x in palavras]

def binary_search(a, x, lo=0, hi=None):   # can't use a to specify default for hi
    hi = hi if hi is not None else len(a) # hi defaults to len(a)   
    pos = bisect_left(a,x,lo,hi)          # find insertion position
    return (pos if pos != hi and a[pos] == x else -1) # don't walk off the end

def buscar(lista, palavra):
    return binary_search(lista, remover_combinantes(palavra))

>>> buscar(palavras_norm, u'programacao')
2
>>> buscar(palavras_norm, u'programação')
2
```

Comment: É, o unidecode é o esquema. Caso você não tenha necessidade de recuperar a palavra original (com os acentos e tal), considere criar um set: `dicionario = set(unidecode.unidecode(p) for p in palavras)` e depois pesquisar com `unidecode.unidecode(busca) in dicionario`.

Answer (score 6):

Existe uma solução mais fácil, ou seja instalar um modulo que faz diretamente este trabalho. Este modulo é o `unidecode`, que existe seja para o Python 2 que para o Python 3.

Se estás num sistema Unix-like, a melhor solução de instalação é usar diretamente no *terminal* o `pip` para o Python 2 ou o `pip3` para o Python 3 na seguinte maneira:

1. `pip install unidecode`

   para o Python 2
2. `pip3 install unidecode`

   para o Python 3

Este aqui é um exemplo pratico e completo usando a lista que destes como exemplo:

```
import unidecode

palavras = [
    u"acentuacao",
    u"divagacão",
    u"programaçao",
    u"taxação",
]

def to_ascii(ls):
    for i in range(len(ls)):
        ls[i] = unidecode.unidecode(ls[i])

to_ascii(palavras)
print(palavras)
```

E o output é o seguinte:

```
['acentuacao', 'divagacao', 'programacao', 'taxacao']
```

Para mais informações sobre o modulo, vê [*aqui*](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode) ou [*aqui*](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode/0.04.1) na *pagina oficial* do Python. Se estás interessado em modificar ou simplesmente ver o código, aqui tens
o [repositorio](https://github.com/avian2/unidecode) no *GitHub*.

Para mais informações ainda, existem pelo menos este [*post*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19771751/how-to-use-unidecode-in-python-3-3) ou [*este*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207457/convert-a-unicode-string-to-a-string-in-python-containing-extra-symbols) no outro SO que podem ser úteis.

Comment: Faz tempo que fiz essa pergunta, na época já haviam sugerido o unidecode (ver [esse comentário](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1761/como-fazer-uma-busca-ignorando-acentua%c3%a7%c3%a3o-em-python/46662#comment1766_1763)) mas por alguma razão que não me lembro decidi por não usá-lo. Preciso fazer alguns testes... De todo modo, é uma boa solução, +1

Answer (score 3):

Você pode escrever um metodo para remover acentos:

```
import unicodedata

def remove_accents(input_str):
    nkfd_form = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', input_str)
    only_ascii = nkfd_form.encode('ASCII', 'ignore')
    return only_ascii

lista = [remove_accents(i) for i in ['é', 'á']]
'e' in lista
```

Assim acredito que seja facil de você levar para sua necessidade!

Comment: O retorno da função no Python 3 é do tipo `bytes` (`<class 'bytes'>`). No entanto, basta chamar o `decode()` no final para retornar uma string comum: `return only_ascii.decode()`

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão, ela funciona, mas tem o efeito colateral de eliminar qualquer caractere não ASCII da string (ex.: `"§"`). Não que esse tipo de caractere seja usado muito na prática... [em buscas] De todo modo, creio que é uma solução válida pra língua porgutuesa pelo menos.