# Como fazer uma busca ignorando acentuação em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, array, acentuação, algoritmo-de-busca

Suponha que eu tenha uma lista de palavras, em JavaScript (se necessário, já [ordenada segundo as regras de *collation*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16496/215)):

```js
var palavras = [
    "acentuacao",
    "divagacão",
    "programaçao",
    "taxação"
];
```

Repare que não usei o cedilha (`ç`) nem o til (`ã`) de forma consistente. Como posso buscar nessa lista por "programação", mas ignorando a acentuação, de modo que várias modalidades de buscas retornem resultados? Ex.:

```js
buscar(palavras, "programacao");
buscar(palavras, "programação");
```

Fiz uma [pergunta semalhante para a linguagem Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1761/215), e tentei aplicar a solução proposta (normalizar e remover combinantes) para JavaScript, mas esbarrei no problema da [falta de suporte à normalização Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7772553/520779). E ainda que eu consiga normalizá-las (usando [um *polyfill*](https://github.com/walling/unorm), por exemplo), ainda faltaria identificar e remover os caracteres combinantes.

Há algo já pronto nesse sentido, para que eu não precise "reinventar a roda"? Caso contrário, como fazer?

---

**Atualização:** Muitas boas respostas, cada uma com seus prós e contras, difícil de escolher uma. Decidi propor um teste levando em consideração 3 fatores:

1. Robustez (i.e. capacidade de buscar por palavras cujo acento está representado de mais de uma forma diferente)

   ```
   'arvore',       // Latin Small Letter A,                         r,v,o,r,e
   '\xe1rvore',    // Latin Small Letter A with acute,              r,v,o,r,e
   'a\u0301rvore', // Latin Small Letter A, Combining Acute Accent, r,v,o,r,e
   ```
2. Flexibilidade (pode buscar ignorando capitalização? pode [só casar o acento com outra letra acentuada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3994/como-fazer-uma-busca-ignorando-acentuacao-em-javascript/4002#comment6047_4002)?)

   ```
                    arvore    árvore
   'arvore'          sim       não
   '\xe1rvore'       sim       sim
   'a\u0301rvore'    sim       sim
   ```
3. Performance (exige mexer na lista original? quanto tempo leva uma operação?)

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/VLVzm/). Vou adequar cada resposta a esse exemplo da melhor forma que puder e availá-la com base nisso. Assim poderemos ter uma resposta canônica.

Comment: Olha só que feio: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5913376/825789

Comment: @bfavaretto hehe é feio, mas é uma solução! Não é como se eu próprio nunca tivesse [feito algo do tipo](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8933546/520779) antes... :P

Comment: Eu já fiz mil vezes. Sua pergunta merecia uma resposta mais elegante, mas não sei se existe.

Comment: Qualquer solução utilizando expressão regular vai cair no mesmo problema de ineficiência. No [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18391901/857807) que @dcastro mencionou existe uma breve explicação sobre isso em inglês. Análise (parsing) de expressão regular é O(n)... Quer dizer, o algoritmo tem que atravessar a String inteira (de tamanho n [e n que pode ser um texto razoavelmente grande]) para realizar a análise. A solução é usar um mapa de caracteres e substituir um por um. Veja a diferença nos gráficos:
http://jsperf.com/diacritics

Comment: O ES6 tem `normalize()`, descobri [nesta resposta na SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37511463/1287812). Fica super fácil.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Como esses caracteres não tem relação relação matemática alguma na tabela unicode. A forma que vejo é fazer a substituição "manualmente", pelo menos usando expressão regular. Dá um trabalho, mas é funcional.

Basicamente:

```
function replaceSpecialChars(str)
{
    str = str.replace(/[ÀÁÂÃÄÅ]/,"A");
    str = str.replace(/[àáâãäå]/,"a");
    str = str.replace(/[ÈÉÊË]/,"E");
    str = str.replace(/[Ç]/,"C");
    str = str.replace(/[ç]/,"c");

    // o resto

    return str.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi,''); 
}
```

No exemplo acima, a opção de case-insensitive não funciona pra substituição em regex. Então você tem de fazer um pra cada versão, minúscula e maiúscula.

Se quiser ver um exemplo funcionando, acesse esse fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e7E4k/

Comment: +1 pois é uma resposta válida (quando se limita o escopo a "acentuação" em vez de "todos os diacríticos" respostas simples ficam viáveis). Só vai se tornar um problema se a entrada tiver tanto caracteres pré-compostos quanto strings onde o diacrítico está separado da letra...

Comment: Referência adicional: o plugin para o jQuery [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) usa uma estratégia semelhante para remover diacríticos, como pode-se ver [nos fontes (linha 101)](https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/blob/master/select2.js).

Comment: [Resultado da avaliação](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/VLVzm/4/): essa solução é robusta (funciona tanto com caracteres pré-compostos quanto com combinantes) e permite busca ignorando capitalização; só não parece ser viável casar acento só com acento; e tanto a lista original quanto o termo de busca têm de ser adaptados, mas a performance é a melhor dentre as soluções já avaliadas.

Comment: Reverti a edição, pois aparentemente o código não está relacionado com a postagem original do @Leonardo.

Comment: Seu jsfiddle está fora do ar.

Answer (score 14):

Algo envolvendo expressões regulares dinâmicas pode resolver de certa forma o problema.
Já tive que fazer algo do tipo no meu plugin jQuery porém não envolvendo acentuação.

Creio que algo assim possa ajudar:

```
String.prototype.toSearch = function () {
    var chars = ['aáàãäâ', 'eéèëê', 'iíìïî', 'oóòõöô', 'uúùüû'],
        value = this;
    for (var i in chars) value = value.replace(new RegExp('[' + chars[i] + ']', 'g'), '[' + chars[i] + ']');
    return new RegExp(value);
};
```

No seu caso a busca creio que ficaria assim:

```
palavras.filter(function(value) {
    return value.search('programação'.toSearch()) > -1;
});
```

Comment: +1 Vejo que a vantagem aqui é não precisar modificar a lista original (a desvantagem é menor performance, mas na maior parte dos casos práticos não deve fazer muita diferença).

Comment: [Resultado da avaliação](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/VLVzm/5/): essa solução não é robusta (não reconhece caracteres combinantes); é bastante flexível (permite busca ignorando acentuação ou casando acento só com acento - mas ainda não consegui fazer com ambos); e como já citado, não precisa adaptar a lista original, mas a performance da busca é um pouco menor.

Comment: (...permite busca ignorando **capitalização**)

Answer (score 12):

Uma solução interessante é criar uma expressão regular com o padrão que você deseja buscar, de forma incluir todas as possíveis acentuações, assim daria `match` no valor desejado.

Código para criar seu padrão:

```
/**
 * Cria uma RegExp que aceita qualquer palavra como string.
 * Ignora acentuação, maiúsculas e minusculas.
 */
function criarPadrao(str) {
    // remove os meta caracteres
    str = str.replace(/([|()[{.+*?^$\\])/g,"\\$1");

    // Separa em palavras
    var words = str.split(/\s+/);

    // ordena pelo tamanho
    words.sort(function (a, b) {
        return b.length - a.length;
    });

    // troca caracteres pelos seus compositores
    var accentReplacer = function(chr) {
        return accented[chr.toUpperCase()] || chr;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        words[i] = words[i].replace(/\S/g, accentReplacer);
    }

    // junta as alternativas
    var regexp = words.join("|");
    return new RegExp(regexp, 'g');
}

// Lista de acentuações possíveis
var accented = {
    'A': '[Aa\xaa\xc0-\xc5\xe0-\xe5\u0100-\u0105\u01cd\u01ce\u0200-\u0203\u0226\u0227\u1d2c\u1d43\u1e00\u1e01\u1e9a\u1ea0-\u1ea3\u2090\u2100\u2101\u213b\u249c\u24b6\u24d0\u3371-\u3374\u3380-\u3384\u3388\u3389\u33a9-\u33af\u33c2\u33ca\u33df\u33ff\uff21\uff41]',
    'B': '[Bb\u1d2e\u1d47\u1e02-\u1e07\u212c\u249d\u24b7\u24d1\u3374\u3385-\u3387\u33c3\u33c8\u33d4\u33dd\uff22\uff42]',
    'C': '[Cc\xc7\xe7\u0106-\u010d\u1d9c\u2100\u2102\u2103\u2105\u2106\u212d\u216d\u217d\u249e\u24b8\u24d2\u3376\u3388\u3389\u339d\u33a0\u33a4\u33c4-\u33c7\uff23\uff43]',
    'D': '[Dd\u010e\u010f\u01c4-\u01c6\u01f1-\u01f3\u1d30\u1d48\u1e0a-\u1e13\u2145\u2146\u216e\u217e\u249f\u24b9\u24d3\u32cf\u3372\u3377-\u3379\u3397\u33ad-\u33af\u33c5\u33c8\uff24\uff44]',
    'E': '[Ee\xc8-\xcb\xe8-\xeb\u0112-\u011b\u0204-\u0207\u0228\u0229\u1d31\u1d49\u1e18-\u1e1b\u1eb8-\u1ebd\u2091\u2121\u212f\u2130\u2147\u24a0\u24ba\u24d4\u3250\u32cd\u32ce\uff25\uff45]',
    'F': '[Ff\u1da0\u1e1e\u1e1f\u2109\u2131\u213b\u24a1\u24bb\u24d5\u338a-\u338c\u3399\ufb00-\ufb04\uff26\uff46]',
    'G': '[Gg\u011c-\u0123\u01e6\u01e7\u01f4\u01f5\u1d33\u1d4d\u1e20\u1e21\u210a\u24a2\u24bc\u24d6\u32cc\u32cd\u3387\u338d-\u338f\u3393\u33ac\u33c6\u33c9\u33d2\u33ff\uff27\uff47]',
    'H': '[Hh\u0124\u0125\u021e\u021f\u02b0\u1d34\u1e22-\u1e2b\u1e96\u210b-\u210e\u24a3\u24bd\u24d7\u32cc\u3371\u3390-\u3394\u33ca\u33cb\u33d7\uff28\uff48]',
    'I': '[Ii\xcc-\xcf\xec-\xef\u0128-\u0130\u0132\u0133\u01cf\u01d0\u0208-\u020b\u1d35\u1d62\u1e2c\u1e2d\u1ec8-\u1ecb\u2071\u2110\u2111\u2139\u2148\u2160-\u2163\u2165-\u2168\u216a\u216b\u2170-\u2173\u2175-\u2178\u217a\u217b\u24a4\u24be\u24d8\u337a\u33cc\u33d5\ufb01\ufb03\uff29\uff49]',
    'J': '[Jj\u0132-\u0135\u01c7-\u01cc\u01f0\u02b2\u1d36\u2149\u24a5\u24bf\u24d9\u2c7c\uff2a\uff4a]',
    'K': '[Kk\u0136\u0137\u01e8\u01e9\u1d37\u1d4f\u1e30-\u1e35\u212a\u24a6\u24c0\u24da\u3384\u3385\u3389\u338f\u3391\u3398\u339e\u33a2\u33a6\u33aa\u33b8\u33be\u33c0\u33c6\u33cd-\u33cf\uff2b\uff4b]',
    'L': '[Ll\u0139-\u0140\u01c7-\u01c9\u02e1\u1d38\u1e36\u1e37\u1e3a-\u1e3d\u2112\u2113\u2121\u216c\u217c\u24a7\u24c1\u24db\u32cf\u3388\u3389\u33d0-\u33d3\u33d5\u33d6\u33ff\ufb02\ufb04\uff2c\uff4c]',
    'M': '[Mm\u1d39\u1d50\u1e3e-\u1e43\u2120\u2122\u2133\u216f\u217f\u24a8\u24c2\u24dc\u3377-\u3379\u3383\u3386\u338e\u3392\u3396\u3399-\u33a8\u33ab\u33b3\u33b7\u33b9\u33bd\u33bf\u33c1\u33c2\u33ce\u33d0\u33d4-\u33d6\u33d8\u33d9\u33de\u33df\uff2d\uff4d]',
    'N': '[Nn\xd1\xf1\u0143-\u0149\u01ca-\u01cc\u01f8\u01f9\u1d3a\u1e44-\u1e4b\u207f\u2115\u2116\u24a9\u24c3\u24dd\u3381\u338b\u339a\u33b1\u33b5\u33bb\u33cc\u33d1\uff2e\uff4e]',
    'O': '[Oo\xba\xd2-\xd6\xf2-\xf6\u014c-\u0151\u01a0\u01a1\u01d1\u01d2\u01ea\u01eb\u020c-\u020f\u022e\u022f\u1d3c\u1d52\u1ecc-\u1ecf\u2092\u2105\u2116\u2134\u24aa\u24c4\u24de\u3375\u33c7\u33d2\u33d6\uff2f\uff4f]',
    'P': '[Pp\u1d3e\u1d56\u1e54-\u1e57\u2119\u24ab\u24c5\u24df\u3250\u3371\u3376\u3380\u338a\u33a9-\u33ac\u33b0\u33b4\u33ba\u33cb\u33d7-\u33da\uff30\uff50]',
    'Q': '[Qq\u211a\u24ac\u24c6\u24e0\u33c3\uff31\uff51]',
    'R': '[Rr\u0154-\u0159\u0210-\u0213\u02b3\u1d3f\u1d63\u1e58-\u1e5b\u1e5e\u1e5f\u20a8\u211b-\u211d\u24ad\u24c7\u24e1\u32cd\u3374\u33ad-\u33af\u33da\u33db\uff32\uff52]',
    'S': '[Ss\u015a-\u0161\u017f\u0218\u0219\u02e2\u1e60-\u1e63\u20a8\u2101\u2120\u24ae\u24c8\u24e2\u33a7\u33a8\u33ae-\u33b3\u33db\u33dc\ufb06\uff33\uff53]',
    'T': '[Tt\u0162-\u0165\u021a\u021b\u1d40\u1d57\u1e6a-\u1e71\u1e97\u2121\u2122\u24af\u24c9\u24e3\u3250\u32cf\u3394\u33cf\ufb05\ufb06\uff34\uff54]',
    'U': '[Uu\xd9-\xdc\xf9-\xfc\u0168-\u0173\u01af\u01b0\u01d3\u01d4\u0214-\u0217\u1d41\u1d58\u1d64\u1e72-\u1e77\u1ee4-\u1ee7\u2106\u24b0\u24ca\u24e4\u3373\u337a\uff35\uff55]',
    'V': '[Vv\u1d5b\u1d65\u1e7c-\u1e7f\u2163-\u2167\u2173-\u2177\u24b1\u24cb\u24e5\u2c7d\u32ce\u3375\u33b4-\u33b9\u33dc\u33de\uff36\uff56]',
    'W': '[Ww\u0174\u0175\u02b7\u1d42\u1e80-\u1e89\u1e98\u24b2\u24cc\u24e6\u33ba-\u33bf\u33dd\uff37\uff57]',
    'X': '[Xx\u02e3\u1e8a-\u1e8d\u2093\u213b\u2168-\u216b\u2178-\u217b\u24b3\u24cd\u24e7\u33d3\uff38\uff58]',
    'Y': '[Yy\xdd\xfd\xff\u0176-\u0178\u0232\u0233\u02b8\u1e8e\u1e8f\u1e99\u1ef2-\u1ef9\u24b4\u24ce\u24e8\u33c9\uff39\uff59]',
    'Z': '[Zz\u0179-\u017e\u01f1-\u01f3\u1dbb\u1e90-\u1e95\u2124\u2128\u24b5\u24cf\u24e9\u3390-\u3394\uff3a\uff5a]'
};
```

Para utilizar é bem simples, segue um exemplo:

```
'coração'.match(criarPadrao('coracao')); // retorna: coração
'coraçao'.match(criarPadrao('coracao')); // retorna: coraçao
'coracao'.match(criarPadrao('coracao')); // retorna: coracao
```

Ou no seu caso:

```
buscar(palavras, criarPadrao('programacao');
```

Onde buscar é algo como:

```
function buscar(palavras, palavraChave) {
    return palavras.find(function (palavra) { 
        return !!palavra.match(criarPadrao(palavraChave));
    });
}
```

Não esqueça que a "palavraChave" não deve conter acento, para que ele busque todos tipos de acento possíveis da letra desejada.

Comment: 'Não esqueça que a "palavraChave" não deve conter acento' é, isso resolve metade do problema, mas o ideal é que o termo de busca pudesse ser acentuado também... As outras respostas são mais simples, mas não têm essa limitação. P.S. por acaso você tem a origem desses códigos que você postou? Poderia postar aqui?

Comment: Já faz um tempo que eu achei esse código na net, eu uso em alguns projetos aqui, se você colocar acentuação na palavra chave, ele vai restringir ao acento usado. Mas da pra remover essa "limitação" se você quiser, é que normalmente se a pessoa coloca o acento, ela está buscando um match com aquele acento especifico.

Comment: Nunca pensei por esse ângulo... Quer dizer que não é um "bug", é uma "feature" hehe. +1

Comment: [Resultado da avaliação](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/VLVzm/6/): essa solução não é robusta (não reconhece caracteres combinantes); **na forma que está** não é flexível (apenas ignora maiúsculas/minúsculas e casa acento com acento, sem meio simples de customização); não precisa modificar a lista original, e a performance está entre as soluções do Leonardo e do Diego.

Answer (score 10):

Remover a acentuação é parte de problema maior (ou deveria ser).

No caso de busca puramente, eu sugiro fortemente utilizar algum mecanismo para "Busca de Texto Completo". Esses mecanismos possuem sofisticados sistemas para analisar o texto e indexa-los. Um famoso sistema open source de busca é o Apache Solr.

Um exemplo bem simples de configurar um fieldType do Solr.

```
<fieldType name="text_keyword" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
 <analyzer>
   <!-- cria token utlizando espaços em branco -->
   <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>

    <!-- palavras transformadas para caixa baixa -->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>

    <!-- remove palavras sem valor semantico. ex: preposicoes -->
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"/>

    <!-- extrai o radical das palavras -->
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>

    <!-- esse filtro remove os acentos --!>
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>

 </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

(você pode ainda tentar utilizar o Lucene que é o motor de indexação debaixo do Solr diretamente numa base de dados, mas ai a solução é ainda mais complicada)

A lista de funcionalidades é bem extensa. Por exemplo, o Solr pode utlizar árvores de busca ternária para fazer busca de sugestões (spell checking), ordenar itens por relevância, ajustar a função de relevância baseado na proximidade dos termos no texto ou em campos arbitrários, etc. Enfim, é um sistema mais apropriado, completo e eficiente para busca.

Caso queira, implementar um sistema de sugestão no lado do cliente você pode e deve adaptar o sistema de transformação de texto que o @dcastro apresentou. Inclusive pode utilizar a cadeia de responsabilidade para realizar as transformações que deseja. Ex:

```
// ... <= inicializacao do mapa diacritico
function letterFilter (str, chain) {
    var letras = str.split("");
    var newStr = "";
    for(var i=0; i< letras.length; i++) {
        var x = letras[i];
        for(var i=0; i < chain.length; i++){
               x = chain[i](x);
        }        
        newStr += x;
    }
    return newStr;
}

function removeDiacritic(letter){
    letter in mapaDiacriticos ? mapaDiacriticos[letter] : letter;
}

function lowerCase(letter){
    reutnr letter.toLowerCase();
}

// simula o sistema de busca de palavras do TextMate 
function starCase(letter){
    return letter + "*";
}

var fs = [removeDiacritic, lowerCase,  starCase];
```

Comment: +1 pela sugestão de usar a cadeia de responsabilidade, é especialmente útil no quesito da flexibilidade (conforme colocado na pergunta). No momento ainda estou dividido entre as respostas, pois a maioria tem sempre um contra (i.e. as robustas são inflexíveis, as flexíveis não são robustas). E Concordo que em geral o ideal é mesmo passar a responsabilidade para o servidor, mas em alguns casos isso não é viável/possível (ex.: quando se usa criptografia no lado cliente); em outros, **algum** processamento no cliente pode ajudar a aliviar a carga no servidor - ainda que ele faça o resto.

Comment: Eu acho que você poderia reconsiderar a questão do encoding mencionado na parte de robustez. Por que?  Bom,  vejo dois possíveis cenários: 1- entrada de dados do usuário_  nesse caso o texto já é unicode e você pode processa-lo normalmente (ex: "letra" por "letra"). 2 - texto guardado em algum lugar que precisa ser comparado com a entrada do usuário. _  você pode ler o texto e já realizar o decoding.  Se o texto for muito grande para caber em memória então você deveria pré-processa-lo.

E assim, seus problemas de múltiplos caracteres acabam. =)

Comment: O problema não é de [*encoding*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_caracteres), e sim de [**normalização**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence).

Comment: Exato. São dois problemas diferentes. 1) Problema é ler o arquivo e transformar o texto numa representação em unicode em memória. 2) Remover os acentos dessa representação. 
Um mecanismo de normalização que trate o problema de encoding estaria "ferindo" a separação de responsabilidades.

Comment: O que quero dizer é que, quando falei de robustez, me referia a normalização, e não encoding. Talvez meu exemplo não esteja claro: `\xe1rvore` (ou `\u00e1rvore`) utiliza o caractere pré-composto ["Latin Small Letter A with acute"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Latin-1_Supplement), enquanto `a\u0301rvore` utiliza ["Latin Small Letter A"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Basic_Latin) seguido de ["Combining Accute Accent"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Combining_Diacritical_Marks). Não há diferença de encoding.

Comment: Você está corretíssimo. É um problema bem razoável porque mapear letra por letra não funciona em UTF-16 por exemplo.

Comment: Sua observação é válida, mas o buraco é mais embaixo: não estou falando de ["Surrogate Pairs"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), eles só se aplicam a caracteres fora do [Plano Multilingual Básico (BMP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) (e acentos nas suas diversas formas ainda fazem parte dele, i.e. gastam apenas um *code unit* em UTF-16). O tópico de Normalização Unicode é novo pra mim, mas esse é um problema que surge **mesmo** que seu encoding permita "mapear letra por letra" (como o UTF-32).

Answer (score 7):

As letras acentuadas chama-se *diacríticos*. Aqui esta' um algoritmo completo que pesquisa e remove todos os diacríticos (de varios idiomas) de uma string, mantendo letras maiusculas/minusculas:

```
var mapaDefault = [
    {'base':'A', 'letras':'\u0041\u24B6\uFF21\u00C0\u00C1\u00C2\u1EA6\u1EA4\u1EAA\u1EA8\u00C3\u0100\u0102\u1EB0\u1EAE\u1EB4\u1EB2\u0226\u01E0\u00C4\u01DE\u1EA2\u00C5\u01FA\u01CD\u0200\u0202\u1EA0\u1EAC\u1EB6\u1E00\u0104\u023A\u2C6F'},
    {'base':'AA','letras':'\uA732'},
    {'base':'AE','letras':'\u00C6\u01FC\u01E2'},
    {'base':'AO','letras':'\uA734'},
    {'base':'AU','letras':'\uA736'},
    {'base':'AV','letras':'\uA738\uA73A'},
    {'base':'AY','letras':'\uA73C'},
    {'base':'B', 'letras':'\u0042\u24B7\uFF22\u1E02\u1E04\u1E06\u0243\u0182\u0181'},
    {'base':'C', 'letras':'\u0043\u24B8\uFF23\u0106\u0108\u010A\u010C\u00C7\u1E08\u0187\u023B\uA73E'},
    {'base':'D', 'letras':'\u0044\u24B9\uFF24\u1E0A\u010E\u1E0C\u1E10\u1E12\u1E0E\u0110\u018B\u018A\u0189\uA779'},
    {'base':'DZ','letras':'\u01F1\u01C4'},
    {'base':'Dz','letras':'\u01F2\u01C5'},
    {'base':'E', 'letras':'\u0045\u24BA\uFF25\u00C8\u00C9\u00CA\u1EC0\u1EBE\u1EC4\u1EC2\u1EBC\u0112\u1E14\u1E16\u0114\u0116\u00CB\u1EBA\u011A\u0204\u0206\u1EB8\u1EC6\u0228\u1E1C\u0118\u1E18\u1E1A\u0190\u018E'},
    {'base':'F', 'letras':'\u0046\u24BB\uFF26\u1E1E\u0191\uA77B'},
    {'base':'G', 'letras':'\u0047\u24BC\uFF27\u01F4\u011C\u1E20\u011E\u0120\u01E6\u0122\u01E4\u0193\uA7A0\uA77D\uA77E'},
    {'base':'H', 'letras':'\u0048\u24BD\uFF28\u0124\u1E22\u1E26\u021E\u1E24\u1E28\u1E2A\u0126\u2C67\u2C75\uA78D'},
    {'base':'I', 'letras':'\u0049\u24BE\uFF29\u00CC\u00CD\u00CE\u0128\u012A\u012C\u0130\u00CF\u1E2E\u1EC8\u01CF\u0208\u020A\u1ECA\u012E\u1E2C\u0197'},
    {'base':'J', 'letras':'\u004A\u24BF\uFF2A\u0134\u0248'},
    {'base':'K', 'letras':'\u004B\u24C0\uFF2B\u1E30\u01E8\u1E32\u0136\u1E34\u0198\u2C69\uA740\uA742\uA744\uA7A2'},
    {'base':'L', 'letras':'\u004C\u24C1\uFF2C\u013F\u0139\u013D\u1E36\u1E38\u013B\u1E3C\u1E3A\u0141\u023D\u2C62\u2C60\uA748\uA746\uA780'},
    {'base':'LJ','letras':'\u01C7'},
    {'base':'Lj','letras':'\u01C8'},
    {'base':'M', 'letras':'\u004D\u24C2\uFF2D\u1E3E\u1E40\u1E42\u2C6E\u019C'},
    {'base':'N', 'letras':'\u004E\u24C3\uFF2E\u01F8\u0143\u00D1\u1E44\u0147\u1E46\u0145\u1E4A\u1E48\u0220\u019D\uA790\uA7A4'},
    {'base':'NJ','letras':'\u01CA'},
    {'base':'Nj','letras':'\u01CB'},
    {'base':'O', 'letras':'\u004F\u24C4\uFF2F\u00D2\u00D3\u00D4\u1ED2\u1ED0\u1ED6\u1ED4\u00D5\u1E4C\u022C\u1E4E\u014C\u1E50\u1E52\u014E\u022E\u0230\u00D6\u022A\u1ECE\u0150\u01D1\u020C\u020E\u01A0\u1EDC\u1EDA\u1EE0\u1EDE\u1EE2\u1ECC\u1ED8\u01EA\u01EC\u00D8\u01FE\u0186\u019F\uA74A\uA74C'},
    {'base':'OI','letras':'\u01A2'},
    {'base':'OO','letras':'\uA74E'},
    {'base':'OU','letras':'\u0222'},
    {'base':'P', 'letras':'\u0050\u24C5\uFF30\u1E54\u1E56\u01A4\u2C63\uA750\uA752\uA754'},
    {'base':'Q', 'letras':'\u0051\u24C6\uFF31\uA756\uA758\u024A'},
    {'base':'R', 'letras':'\u0052\u24C7\uFF32\u0154\u1E58\u0158\u0210\u0212\u1E5A\u1E5C\u0156\u1E5E\u024C\u2C64\uA75A\uA7A6\uA782'},
    {'base':'S', 'letras':'\u0053\u24C8\uFF33\u1E9E\u015A\u1E64\u015C\u1E60\u0160\u1E66\u1E62\u1E68\u0218\u015E\u2C7E\uA7A8\uA784'},
    {'base':'T', 'letras':'\u0054\u24C9\uFF34\u1E6A\u0164\u1E6C\u021A\u0162\u1E70\u1E6E\u0166\u01AC\u01AE\u023E\uA786'},
    {'base':'TZ','letras':'\uA728'},
    {'base':'U', 'letras':'\u0055\u24CA\uFF35\u00D9\u00DA\u00DB\u0168\u1E78\u016A\u1E7A\u016C\u00DC\u01DB\u01D7\u01D5\u01D9\u1EE6\u016E\u0170\u01D3\u0214\u0216\u01AF\u1EEA\u1EE8\u1EEE\u1EEC\u1EF0\u1EE4\u1E72\u0172\u1E76\u1E74\u0244'},
    {'base':'V', 'letras':'\u0056\u24CB\uFF36\u1E7C\u1E7E\u01B2\uA75E\u0245'},
    {'base':'VY','letras':'\uA760'},
    {'base':'W', 'letras':'\u0057\u24CC\uFF37\u1E80\u1E82\u0174\u1E86\u1E84\u1E88\u2C72'},
    {'base':'X', 'letras':'\u0058\u24CD\uFF38\u1E8A\u1E8C'},
    {'base':'Y', 'letras':'\u0059\u24CE\uFF39\u1EF2\u00DD\u0176\u1EF8\u0232\u1E8E\u0178\u1EF6\u1EF4\u01B3\u024E\u1EFE'},
    {'base':'Z', 'letras':'\u005A\u24CF\uFF3A\u0179\u1E90\u017B\u017D\u1E92\u1E94\u01B5\u0224\u2C7F\u2C6B\uA762'},
    {'base':'a', 'letras':'\u0061\u24D0\uFF41\u1E9A\u00E0\u00E1\u00E2\u1EA7\u1EA5\u1EAB\u1EA9\u00E3\u0101\u0103\u1EB1\u1EAF\u1EB5\u1EB3\u0227\u01E1\u00E4\u01DF\u1EA3\u00E5\u01FB\u01CE\u0201\u0203\u1EA1\u1EAD\u1EB7\u1E01\u0105\u2C65\u0250'},
    {'base':'aa','letras':'\uA733'},
    {'base':'ae','letras':'\u00E6\u01FD\u01E3'},
    {'base':'ao','letras':'\uA735'},
    {'base':'au','letras':'\uA737'},
    {'base':'av','letras':'\uA739\uA73B'},
    {'base':'ay','letras':'\uA73D'},
    {'base':'b', 'letras':'\u0062\u24D1\uFF42\u1E03\u1E05\u1E07\u0180\u0183\u0253'},
    {'base':'c', 'letras':'\u0063\u24D2\uFF43\u0107\u0109\u010B\u010D\u00E7\u1E09\u0188\u023C\uA73F\u2184'},
    {'base':'d', 'letras':'\u0064\u24D3\uFF44\u1E0B\u010F\u1E0D\u1E11\u1E13\u1E0F\u0111\u018C\u0256\u0257\uA77A'},
    {'base':'dz','letras':'\u01F3\u01C6'},
    {'base':'e', 'letras':'\u0065\u24D4\uFF45\u00E8\u00E9\u00EA\u1EC1\u1EBF\u1EC5\u1EC3\u1EBD\u0113\u1E15\u1E17\u0115\u0117\u00EB\u1EBB\u011B\u0205\u0207\u1EB9\u1EC7\u0229\u1E1D\u0119\u1E19\u1E1B\u0247\u025B\u01DD'},
    {'base':'f', 'letras':'\u0066\u24D5\uFF46\u1E1F\u0192\uA77C'},
    {'base':'g', 'letras':'\u0067\u24D6\uFF47\u01F5\u011D\u1E21\u011F\u0121\u01E7\u0123\u01E5\u0260\uA7A1\u1D79\uA77F'},
    {'base':'h', 'letras':'\u0068\u24D7\uFF48\u0125\u1E23\u1E27\u021F\u1E25\u1E29\u1E2B\u1E96\u0127\u2C68\u2C76\u0265'},
    {'base':'hv','letras':'\u0195'},
    {'base':'i', 'letras':'\u0069\u24D8\uFF49\u00EC\u00ED\u00EE\u0129\u012B\u012D\u00EF\u1E2F\u1EC9\u01D0\u0209\u020B\u1ECB\u012F\u1E2D\u0268\u0131'},
    {'base':'j', 'letras':'\u006A\u24D9\uFF4A\u0135\u01F0\u0249'},
    {'base':'k', 'letras':'\u006B\u24DA\uFF4B\u1E31\u01E9\u1E33\u0137\u1E35\u0199\u2C6A\uA741\uA743\uA745\uA7A3'},
    {'base':'l', 'letras':'\u006C\u24DB\uFF4C\u0140\u013A\u013E\u1E37\u1E39\u013C\u1E3D\u1E3B\u017F\u0142\u019A\u026B\u2C61\uA749\uA781\uA747'},
    {'base':'lj','letras':'\u01C9'},
    {'base':'m', 'letras':'\u006D\u24DC\uFF4D\u1E3F\u1E41\u1E43\u0271\u026F'},
    {'base':'n', 'letras':'\u006E\u24DD\uFF4E\u01F9\u0144\u00F1\u1E45\u0148\u1E47\u0146\u1E4B\u1E49\u019E\u0272\u0149\uA791\uA7A5'},
    {'base':'nj','letras':'\u01CC'},
    {'base':'o', 'letras':'\u006F\u24DE\uFF4F\u00F2\u00F3\u00F4\u1ED3\u1ED1\u1ED7\u1ED5\u00F5\u1E4D\u022D\u1E4F\u014D\u1E51\u1E53\u014F\u022F\u0231\u00F6\u022B\u1ECF\u0151\u01D2\u020D\u020F\u01A1\u1EDD\u1EDB\u1EE1\u1EDF\u1EE3\u1ECD\u1ED9\u01EB\u01ED\u00F8\u01FF\u0254\uA74B\uA74D\u0275'},
    {'base':'oi','letras':'\u01A3'},
    {'base':'ou','letras':'\u0223'},
    {'base':'oo','letras':'\uA74F'},
    {'base':'p','letras':'\u0070\u24DF\uFF50\u1E55\u1E57\u01A5\u1D7D\uA751\uA753\uA755'},
    {'base':'q','letras':'\u0071\u24E0\uFF51\u024B\uA757\uA759'},
    {'base':'r','letras':'\u0072\u24E1\uFF52\u0155\u1E59\u0159\u0211\u0213\u1E5B\u1E5D\u0157\u1E5F\u024D\u027D\uA75B\uA7A7\uA783'},
    {'base':'s','letras':'\u0073\u24E2\uFF53\u00DF\u015B\u1E65\u015D\u1E61\u0161\u1E67\u1E63\u1E69\u0219\u015F\u023F\uA7A9\uA785\u1E9B'},
    {'base':'t','letras':'\u0074\u24E3\uFF54\u1E6B\u1E97\u0165\u1E6D\u021B\u0163\u1E71\u1E6F\u0167\u01AD\u0288\u2C66\uA787'},
    {'base':'tz','letras':'\uA729'},
    {'base':'u','letras': '\u0075\u24E4\uFF55\u00F9\u00FA\u00FB\u0169\u1E79\u016B\u1E7B\u016D\u00FC\u01DC\u01D8\u01D6\u01DA\u1EE7\u016F\u0171\u01D4\u0215\u0217\u01B0\u1EEB\u1EE9\u1EEF\u1EED\u1EF1\u1EE5\u1E73\u0173\u1E77\u1E75\u0289'},
    {'base':'v','letras':'\u0076\u24E5\uFF56\u1E7D\u1E7F\u028B\uA75F\u028C'},
    {'base':'vy','letras':'\uA761'},
    {'base':'w','letras':'\u0077\u24E6\uFF57\u1E81\u1E83\u0175\u1E87\u1E85\u1E98\u1E89\u2C73'},
    {'base':'x','letras':'\u0078\u24E7\uFF58\u1E8B\u1E8D'},
    {'base':'y','letras':'\u0079\u24E8\uFF59\u1EF3\u00FD\u0177\u1EF9\u0233\u1E8F\u00FF\u1EF7\u1E99\u1EF5\u01B4\u024F\u1EFF'},
    {'base':'z','letras':'\u007A\u24E9\uFF5A\u017A\u1E91\u017C\u017E\u1E93\u1E95\u01B6\u0225\u0240\u2C6C\uA763'}
];

var mapaDiacriticos = {};
for (var i=0; i < mapaDefault.length; i++){
    var letras = mapaDefault[i].letras.split("");
    for (var j=0; j < letras.length ; j++){
        mapaDiacriticos[letras[j]] = mapaDefault[i].base;
    }
}

function removeDiacriticos (str) {
    var letras = str.split("");
    var newStr = "";
    for(var i=0; i< letras.length; i++) {
        newStr += letras[i] in mapaDiacriticos ? mapaDiacriticos[letras[i]] : letras[i];
    }
    return newStr;
}
```

Fonte: [Javascript : remove accents in strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18391901/857807)

Comment: [Resultado da avaliação](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/VLVzm/7/): essa solução não é robusta (não reconhece caracteres combinantes); permite busca ignorando capitalização, mas não parece ser viável casar acento só com acento; tanto a lista original quanto o termo de busca precisam ser adaptados, e a performance está entre as soluções do Leonardo e do Gabriel.

Answer (score 5):

Você pode criar um "Slug" da string e após isso fazer uma busca, como o código abaixo

```
String.prototype.toSlug = function(){
    str = this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); // trim
    str = str.toLowerCase();

    // remove accents, swap ñ for n, etc
    var from = "ãàáäâèéëêìíïîõòóöôùúüûñç·/_,:;";
    var to   = "aaaaaeeeeiiiiooooouuuunc------";
    for (var i=0, l=from.length ; i<l ; i++) {
        str = str.replace(new RegExp(from.charAt(i), 'g'), to.charAt(i));
    }

    str = str.replace(/[^a-z0-9 -]/g, '').replace(/\s+/g, '-').replace(/-+/g, '-');

    return str;
};


String.prototype.toSearch = function(query) {
    var str = this.toSlug();

    return this.toSlug().search(new RegExp(query.toLowerCase(), 'i'));
};


var str = 'São Paulo';
$('#search').click(function() {
    alert(str.toSearch('Paulo'));
});
```

Segue um exemplo http://jsfiddle.net/ELvvv/

Comment: [Resultado da avaliação](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/VLVzm/8/): essa solução é robusta (funciona tanto com caracteres pré-compostos quanto com combinantes); **na forma como está** não é flexível (sempre busca ignorando capitalização; só não parece ser viável casar acento só com acento); tanto a lista original quanto o termo de busca têm de ser adaptados; a performance da preparação da lista é baixa, mas a da busca é a segunda mais alta dentre as soluções avaliadas.