# Recuperar data e hora local de um dia arbitrário em um timezone arbitrário, considerando horário de verão

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone

Quero mostrar o dia, hora, minuto etc. em um timezone arbitrário, em um dia arbitrário. Como falar de conversão de timezones é sempre difícil e confuso, e como falar de conversões de timezones *em JavaScript* é ainda mais difícil e confuso, vou tentar *meio que* formalizar a questão:

Busco uma função `f(t, s)` que:

- dado o timestamp 1357041600 (que 2013/1/1 12:00:00 UTC) e a string `"America/São Paulo"`, satisfaça a igualdade abaixo:

  ```
  f(1357041600, "America/São Paulo") == "2013/01/01 10:00:00"
  ```
- dado o timestamp 1372680000 (2013/07/01 12:00:00 UTC), satisfaça a igualdade abaixo:

  ```
  f(1357041600, "America/São Paulo") == "2013/07/01 09:00:00"
  ```
- se comporte sempre desta maneira independentemente do timezone da máquina onde o browser roda (mesmo que seja, digamos `"Europe/London"` ou `"America/Los Angeles"`).
- se se comporte sempre desta maneira independentemente da hora na máquina onde o browser roda (mesmo que seja 2014/02/05 19:32, ou 2002/08/04 07:12)
- e, por fim, não se comunique com código rodando em algum servidor (porque eu mesmo já tô quase apelando para isso :) )

Isso é possível?

Comment: Deu uma olhada à minha resposta? Fico curioso se resolve o seu problema.

Answer (score 7):

Esta função não existe nativa no javascript, têm de ser feita "à mão" ou então usando uma biblioteca.

Assim, aqui fica uma que fiz agora (entre ontem à noite e hoje):

Primeiro, declare [todas as zonas de tempo](http://gomashup.com/json.php?fds=geo/timezone/locations&jsoncallback=?) em um JSON:

```json
var olson = '{"result":[{"TimeZoneId":"Africa/Abidjan","DST":"0","GMT":"0"},{"TimeZoneId":"Africa/Accra","DST":"0","GMT":"0"},{"TimeZoneId":"Africa/Addis Ababa","DST":"3","GMT":"3"},{"TimeZoneId":"Africa/Algiers","DST":"1","GMT":"1"},{"TimeZoneId":"Africa/Asmara","DST":"3","GMT":"3"},{"TimeZoneId":"Africa/Bamako","DST":"0","GMT":"0"},{"TimeZoneId":"Africa/Bangui","DST":"1","GMT":"1"},{"TimeZoneId":"Africa/Banjul","DST":"0","GMT":"0"},{"TimeZoneId":"Africa/Bissau","DST":"0","GMT":"0"},{"TimeZoneId":"Africa/Blantyre","DST":"2","GMT":"2"},{"TimeZoneId":"Africa/Brazzaville","DST":"1","GMT":"1"},{"TimeZoneId":"Africa/Bujumbura","DST":"2","GMT":"2"},{"TimeZoneId":"Africa/Cairo","DST":"3","GMT":"2"},{"TimeZoneId":"Africa/Casablanca","DST":"0","GMT":"0"},{"TimeZoneId":"Africa/Ceuta","DST":"2","GMT":"1"},{"TimeZoneId":"Africa/Conakry","DST":"0","GMT":"0"},{"TimeZoneId":"Africa/Dakar","DST":"0","GMT":"0"},{"TimeZoneId":"Africa/Dar es Salaam","DST":"3","GMT":"3"},{"TimeZoneId":"Africa/Djibouti","DST":"3","GMT":"3"},{"TimeZoneId":"Africa/Douala","DST":"1","GMT":"1"},{"TimeZoneId":"Africa/El Aaiun","DST":"0","GMT":"0"},{"TimeZoneId":"Africa/Freetown","DST":"0","GMT":"0"},{"TimeZoneId":"Africa/Gaborone","DST":"2","GMT":"2"},{"TimeZoneId":"Africa/Harare","DST":"2","GMT":"2"},{"TimeZoneId":"Africa/Johannesburg","DST":"2","GMT":"2"},{"TimeZoneId":"Africa/Kampala","DST":"3","GMT":"3"},{"TimeZoneId":"Africa/Khartoum","DST":"3","GMT":"3"},{"TimeZoneId":"Africa/Kigali","DST":"2","GMT":"2"},{"TimeZoneId":"Africa/Kinshasa","DST":"1","GMT":"1"},{"TimeZoneId":"Africa/Lagos","DST":"1","GMT":"1"},{"TimeZoneId":"Africa/Libreville","DST":"1","GMT":"1"},{"TimeZoneId":"Africa/Lome","DST":"0","GMT":"0"},{"TimeZoneId":"Africa/Luanda","DST":"1","GMT":"1"},{"TimeZoneId":"Africa/Lubumbashi","DST":"2","GMT":"2"},{"TimeZoneId":"Africa/Lusaka","DST":"2","GMT":"2"},{"TimeZoneId":"Africa/Malabo","DST":"1","GMT":"1"},{"TimeZoneId":"Africa/Maputo","DST":"2","GMT":"2"},{"TimeZoneId":"Africa/Maseru","DST":"2","GMT":"2"},{"TimeZoneId":"Africa/Mbabane","DST":"2","GMT":"2"},{"TimeZoneId":"Africa/Mogadishu","DST":"3","GMT":"3"},{"TimeZoneId":"Africa/Monrovia","DST":"0","GMT":"0"},{"TimeZoneId":"Africa/Nairobi","DST":"3","GMT":"3"},{"TimeZoneId":"Africa/Ndjamena","DST":"1","GMT":"1"},{"TimeZoneId":"Africa/Niamey","DST":"1","GMT":"1"},{"TimeZoneId":"Africa/Nouakchott","DST":"0","GMT":"0"},{"TimeZoneId":"Africa/Ouagadougou","DST":"0","GMT":"0"},{"TimeZoneId":"Africa/Porto/Novo","DST":"1","GMT":"1"},{"TimeZoneId":"Africa/Sao Tome","DST":"0","GMT":"0"},{"TimeZoneId":"Africa/Tripoli","DST":"2","GMT":"2"},{"TimeZoneId":"Africa/Tunis","DST":"2","GMT":"1"},{"TimeZoneId":"Africa/Windhoek","DST":"1","GMT":"2"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Adak","DST":"-9","GMT":"-10"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Anchorage","DST":"-8","GMT":"-9"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Anguilla","DST":"-4","GMT":"-4"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Antigua","DST":"-4","GMT":"-4"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Araguaina","DST":"-3","GMT":"-3"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Argentina/Buenos Aires","DST":"-3","GMT":"-3"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Argentina/Catamarca","DST":"-3","GMT":"-3"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Argentina/Cordoba","DST":"-3","GMT":"-3"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Argentina/Jujuy","DST":"-3","GMT":"-3"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Argentina/La Rioja","DST":"-3","GMT":"-3"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Argentina/Mendoza","DST":"-3","GMT":"-3"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Argentina/Rio Gallegos","DST":"-3","GMT":"-3"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Argentina/Salta","DST":"-3","GMT":"-3"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Argentina/San Juan","DST":"-3","GMT":"-3"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Argentina/San Luis","DST":"-4","GMT":"-3"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Argentina/Tucuman","DST":"-3","GMT":"-3"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Argentina/Ushuaia","DST":"-3","GMT":"-3"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Aruba","DST":"-4","GMT":"-4"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Asuncion","DST":"-4","GMT":"-3"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Atikokan","DST":"-5","GMT":"-5"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Bahia","DST":"-3","GMT":"-3"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Barbados","DST":"-4","GMT":"-4"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Belem","DST":"-3","GMT":"-3"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Belize","DST":"-6","GMT":"-6"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Blanc/Sablon","DST":"-4","GMT":"-4"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Boa Vista","DST":"-4","GMT":"-4"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Bogota","DST":"-5","GMT":"-5"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Boise","DST":"-6","GMT":"-7"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Cambridge Bay","DST":"-6","GMT":"-7"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Campo Grande","DST":"-4","GMT":"-3"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Cancun","DST":"-5","GMT":"-6"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Caracas","DST":"-4.5","GMT":"-4.5"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Cayenne","DST":"-3","GMT":"-3"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Cayman","DST":"-5","GMT":"-5"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Chicago","DST":"-5","GMT":"-6"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Chihuahua","DST":"-6","GMT":"-7"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Costa Rica","DST":"-6","GMT":"-6"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Cuiaba","DST":"-4","GMT":"-3"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Curacao","DST":"-4","GMT":"-4"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Danmarkshavn","DST":"0","GMT":"0"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Dawson","DST":"-7","GMT":"-8"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Dawson Creek","DST":"-7","GMT":"-7"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Denver","DST":"-6","GMT":"-7"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Detroit","DST":"-4","GMT":"-5"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Dominica","DST":"-4","GMT":"-4"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Edmonton","DST":"-6","GMT":"-7"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Eirunepe","DST":"-4","GMT":"-4"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/El Salvador","DST":"-6","GMT":"-6"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Fortaleza","DST":"-3","GMT":"-3"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Glace Bay","DST":"-3","GMT":"-4"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Godthab","DST":"-2","GMT":"-3"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Goose Bay","DST":"-3","GMT":"-4"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Grand Turk","DST":"-4","GMT":"-5"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Grenada","DST":"-4","GMT":"-4"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Guadeloupe","DST":"-4","GMT":"-4"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Guatemala","DST":"-6","GMT":"-6"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Guayaquil","DST":"-5","GMT":"-5"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Guyana","DST":"-4","GMT":"-4"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Halifax","DST":"-3","GMT":"-4"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Havana","DST":"-4","GMT":"-5"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Hermosillo","DST":"-7","GMT":"-7"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Indiana/Indianapolis","DST":"-4","GMT":"-5"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Indiana/Knox","DST":"-5","GMT":"-6"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Indiana/Marengo","DST":"-4","GMT":"-5"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Indiana/Petersburg","DST":"-4","GMT":"-5"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Indiana/Tell City","DST":"-5","GMT":"-6"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Indiana/Vevay","DST":"-4","GMT":"-5"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Indiana/Vincennes","DST":"-4","GMT":"-5"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Indiana/Winamac","DST":"-4","GMT":"-5"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Inuvik","DST":"-6","GMT":"-7"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Iqaluit","DST":"-4","GMT":"-5"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Jamaica","DST":"-5","GMT":"-5"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Juneau","DST":"-8","GMT":"-9"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Kentucky/Louisville","DST":"-4","GMT":"-5"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Kentucky/Monticello","DST":"-4","GMT":"-5"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/La Paz","DST":"-4","GMT":"-4"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Lima","DST":"-5","GMT":"-5"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Los Angeles","DST":"-7","GMT":"-8"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Maceio","DST":"-3","GMT":"-3"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Managua","DST":"-6","GMT":"-6"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Manaus","DST":"-4","GMT":"-4"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Marigot","DST":"-4","GMT":"-4"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Martinique","DST":"-4","GMT":"-4"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Matamoros","DST":"0","GMT":"0"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Mazatlan","DST":"-6","GMT":"-7"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Menominee","DST":"-5","GMT":"-6"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Merida","DST":"-5","GMT":"-6"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Mexico City","DST":"-5","GMT":"-6"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Miquelon","DST":"-2","GMT":"-3"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Moncton","DST":"-3","GMT":"-4"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Monterrey","DST":"-5","GMT":"-6"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Montevideo","DST":"-3","GMT":"-2"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Montreal","DST":"-4","GMT":"-5"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Montserrat","DST":"-4","GMT":"-4"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Nassau","DST":"-4","GMT":"-5"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/New York","DST":"-4","GMT":"-5"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Nipigon","DST":"-4","GMT":"-5"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Nome","DST":"-8","GMT":"-9"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Noronha","DST":"-2","GMT":"-2"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/North Dakota/Center","DST":"-5","GMT":"-6"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/North Dakota/New Salem","DST":"-5","GMT":"-6"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Ojinaga","DST":"0","GMT":"0"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Panama","DST":"-5","GMT":"-5"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Pangnirtung","DST":"-4","GMT":"-5"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Paramaribo","DST":"-3","GMT":"-3"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Phoenix","DST":"-7","GMT":"-7"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Port/au/Prince","DST":"-5","GMT":"-5"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Port of Spain","DST":"-4","GMT":"-4"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Porto Velho","DST":"-4","GMT":"-4"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Puerto Rico","DST":"-4","GMT":"-4"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Rainy River","DST":"-5","GMT":"-6"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Rankin Inlet","DST":"-5","GMT":"-6"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Recife","DST":"-3","GMT":"-3"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Regina","DST":"-6","GMT":"-6"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Resolute","DST":"-5","GMT":"-5"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Rio Branco","DST":"-4","GMT":"-4"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Santa Isabel","DST":"0","GMT":"0"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Santarem","DST":"-3","GMT":"-3"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Santiago","DST":"-4","GMT":"-3"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Santo Domingo","DST":"-4","GMT":"-4"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Sao Paulo","DST":"-3","GMT":"-2"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Scoresbysund","DST":"0","GMT":"-1"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Shiprock","DST":"-6","GMT":"-7"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/St Barthelemy","DST":"-4","GMT":"-4"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/St Johns","DST":"-2.5","GMT":"-3.5"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/St Kitts","DST":"-4","GMT":"-4"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/St Lucia","DST":"-4","GMT":"-4"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/St Thomas","DST":"-4","GMT":"-4"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/St Vincent","DST":"-4","GMT":"-4"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Swift Current","DST":"-6","GMT":"-6"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Tegucigalpa","DST":"-6","GMT":"-6"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Thule","DST":"-3","GMT":"-4"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Thunder Bay","DST":"-4","GMT":"-5"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Tijuana","DST":"-7","GMT":"-8"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Toronto","DST":"-4","GMT":"-5"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Tortola","DST":"-4","GMT":"-4"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Vancouver","DST":"-7","GMT":"-8"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Whitehorse","DST":"-7","GMT":"-8"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Winnipeg","DST":"-5","GMT":"-6"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Yakutat","DST":"-8","GMT":"-9"},{"TimeZoneId":"America/Yellowknife","DST":"-6","GMT":"-7"},{"TimeZoneId":"Antarctica/Casey","DST":"11","GMT":"11"},{"TimeZoneId":"Antarctica/Davis","DST":"5","GMT":"5"},{"TimeZoneId":"Antarctica/DumontDUrville","DST":"10","GMT":"10"},{"TimeZoneId":"Antarctica/Mawson","DST":"5","GMT":"5"},{"TimeZoneId":"Antarctica/McMurdo","DST":"12","GMT":"13"},{"TimeZoneId":"Antarctica/Palmer","DST":"-4","GMT":"-3"},{"TimeZoneId":"Antarctica/Rothera","DST":"-3","GMT":"-3"},{"TimeZoneId":"Antarctica/South Pole","DST":"12","GMT":"13"},{"TimeZoneId":"Antarctica/Syowa","DST":"3","GMT":"3"},{"TimeZoneId":"Antarctica/Vostok","DST":"6","GMT":"6"},{"TimeZoneId":"Arctic/Longyearbyen","DST":"2","GMT":"1"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Aden","DST":"3","GMT":"3"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Almaty","DST":"6","GMT":"6"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Amman","DST":"3","GMT":"2"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Anadyr","DST":"13","GMT":"12"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Aqtau","DST":"5","GMT":"5"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Aqtobe","DST":"5","GMT":"5"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Ashgabat","DST":"5","GMT":"5"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Baghdad","DST":"3","GMT":"3"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Bahrain","DST":"3","GMT":"3"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Baku","DST":"5","GMT":"4"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Bangkok","DST":"7","GMT":"7"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Beirut","DST":"3","GMT":"2"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Bishkek","DST":"6","GMT":"6"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Brunei","DST":"8","GMT":"8"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Choibalsan","DST":"8","GMT":"8"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Chongqing","DST":"8","GMT":"8"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Colombo","DST":"5.5","GMT":"5.5"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Damascus","DST":"3","GMT":"2"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Dhaka","DST":"7","GMT":"6"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Dili","DST":"9","GMT":"9"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Dubai","DST":"4","GMT":"4"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Dushanbe","DST":"5","GMT":"5"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Gaza","DST":"3","GMT":"2"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Harbin","DST":"8","GMT":"8"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Ho Chi Minh","DST":"7","GMT":"7"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Hong Kong","DST":"8","GMT":"8"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Hovd","DST":"7","GMT":"7"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Irkutsk","DST":"9","GMT":"8"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Jakarta","DST":"7","GMT":"7"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Jayapura","DST":"9","GMT":"9"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Jerusalem","DST":"3","GMT":"2"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Kabul","DST":"4.5","GMT":"4.5"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Kamchatka","DST":"13","GMT":"12"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Karachi","DST":"6","GMT":"5"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Kashgar","DST":"8","GMT":"8"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Kathmandu","DST":"5.75","GMT":"5.75"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Kolkata","DST":"5.5","GMT":"5.5"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Krasnoyarsk","DST":"8","GMT":"7"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Kuala Lumpur","DST":"8","GMT":"8"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Kuching","DST":"8","GMT":"8"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Kuwait","DST":"3","GMT":"3"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Macau","DST":"8","GMT":"8"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Magadan","DST":"12","GMT":"11"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Makassar","DST":"8","GMT":"8"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Manila","DST":"8","GMT":"8"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Muscat","DST":"4","GMT":"4"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Nicosia","DST":"3","GMT":"2"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Novokuznetsk","DST":"7","GMT":"7"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Novosibirsk","DST":"7","GMT":"6"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Omsk","DST":"7","GMT":"6"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Oral","DST":"5","GMT":"5"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Phnom Penh","DST":"7","GMT":"7"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Pontianak","DST":"7","GMT":"7"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Pyongyang","DST":"9","GMT":"9"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Qatar","DST":"3","GMT":"3"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Qyzylorda","DST":"6","GMT":"6"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Rangoon","DST":"6.5","GMT":"6.5"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Riyadh","DST":"3","GMT":"3"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Sakhalin","DST":"11","GMT":"10"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Samarkand","DST":"5","GMT":"5"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Seoul","DST":"9","GMT":"9"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Shanghai","DST":"8","GMT":"8"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Singapore","DST":"8","GMT":"8"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Taipei","DST":"8","GMT":"8"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Tashkent","DST":"5","GMT":"5"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Tbilisi","DST":"4","GMT":"4"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Tehran","DST":"4.5","GMT":"3.5"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Thimphu","DST":"6","GMT":"6"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Tokyo","DST":"9","GMT":"9"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Ulaanbaatar","DST":"8","GMT":"8"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Urumqi","DST":"8","GMT":"8"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Vientiane","DST":"7","GMT":"7"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Vladivostok","DST":"11","GMT":"10"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Yakutsk","DST":"10","GMT":"9"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Yekaterinburg","DST":"6","GMT":"5"},{"TimeZoneId":"Asia/Yerevan","DST":"5","GMT":"4"},{"TimeZoneId":"Atlantic/Azores","DST":"0","GMT":"-1"},{"TimeZoneId":"Atlantic/Bermuda","DST":"-3","GMT":"-4"},{"TimeZoneId":"Atlantic/Canary","DST":"1","GMT":"0"},{"TimeZoneId":"Atlantic/Cape Verde","DST":"-1","GMT":"-1"},{"TimeZoneId":"Atlantic/Faroe","DST":"1","GMT":"0"},{"TimeZoneId":"Atlantic/Madeira","DST":"1","GMT":"0"},{"TimeZoneId":"Atlantic/Reykjavik","DST":"0","GMT":"0"},{"TimeZoneId":"Atlantic/South Georgia","DST":"-2","GMT":"-2"},{"TimeZoneId":"Atlantic/St Helena","DST":"0","GMT":"0"},{"TimeZoneId":"Atlantic/Stanley","DST":"-4","GMT":"-3"},{"TimeZoneId":"Australia/Adelaide","DST":"9.5","GMT":"10.5"},{"TimeZoneId":"Australia/Brisbane","DST":"10","GMT":"10"},{"TimeZoneId":"Australia/Broken Hill","DST":"9.5","GMT":"10.5"},{"TimeZoneId":"Australia/Currie","DST":"10","GMT":"11"},{"TimeZoneId":"Australia/Darwin","DST":"9.5","GMT":"9.5"},{"TimeZoneId":"Australia/Eucla","DST":"8.75","GMT":"8.75"},{"TimeZoneId":"Australia/Hobart","DST":"10","GMT":"11"},{"TimeZoneId":"Australia/Lindeman","DST":"10","GMT":"10"},{"TimeZoneId":"Australia/Lord Howe","DST":"10.5","GMT":"11"},{"TimeZoneId":"Australia/Melbourne","DST":"10","GMT":"11"},{"TimeZoneId":"Australia/Perth","DST":"8","GMT":"8"},{"TimeZoneId":"Australia/Sydney","DST":"10","GMT":"11"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Amsterdam","DST":"2","GMT":"1"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Andorra","DST":"2","GMT":"1"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Athens","DST":"3","GMT":"2"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Belgrade","DST":"2","GMT":"1"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Berlin","DST":"2","GMT":"1"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Bratislava","DST":"2","GMT":"1"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Brussels","DST":"2","GMT":"1"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Bucharest","DST":"3","GMT":"2"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Budapest","DST":"2","GMT":"1"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Chisinau","DST":"3","GMT":"2"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Copenhagen","DST":"2","GMT":"1"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Dublin","DST":"1","GMT":"0"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Gibraltar","DST":"2","GMT":"1"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Guernsey","DST":"1","GMT":"0"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Helsinki","DST":"3","GMT":"2"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Isle of Man","DST":"1","GMT":"0"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Istanbul","DST":"3","GMT":"2"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Jersey","DST":"1","GMT":"0"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Kaliningrad","DST":"3","GMT":"2"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Kiev","DST":"3","GMT":"2"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Lisbon","DST":"1","GMT":"0"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Ljubljana","DST":"2","GMT":"1"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/London","DST":"1","GMT":"0"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Luxembourg","DST":"2","GMT":"1"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Madrid","DST":"2","GMT":"1"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Malta","DST":"2","GMT":"1"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Mariehamn","DST":"3","GMT":"2"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Minsk","DST":"3","GMT":"2"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Monaco","DST":"2","GMT":"1"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Moscow","DST":"4","GMT":"3"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Oslo","DST":"2","GMT":"1"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Paris","DST":"2","GMT":"1"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Podgorica","DST":"2","GMT":"1"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Prague","DST":"2","GMT":"1"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Riga","DST":"3","GMT":"2"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Rome","DST":"2","GMT":"1"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Samara","DST":"5","GMT":"4"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/San Marino","DST":"2","GMT":"1"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Sarajevo","DST":"2","GMT":"1"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Simferopol","DST":"3","GMT":"2"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Skopje","DST":"2","GMT":"1"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Sofia","DST":"3","GMT":"2"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Stockholm","DST":"2","GMT":"1"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Tallinn","DST":"3","GMT":"2"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Tirane","DST":"2","GMT":"1"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Uzhgorod","DST":"3","GMT":"2"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Vaduz","DST":"2","GMT":"1"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Vatican","DST":"2","GMT":"1"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Vienna","DST":"2","GMT":"1"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Vilnius","DST":"3","GMT":"2"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Volgograd","DST":"4","GMT":"3"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Warsaw","DST":"2","GMT":"1"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Zagreb","DST":"2","GMT":"1"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Zaporozhye","DST":"3","GMT":"2"},{"TimeZoneId":"Europe/Zurich","DST":"2","GMT":"1"},{"TimeZoneId":"Indian/Antananarivo","DST":"3","GMT":"3"},{"TimeZoneId":"Indian/Chagos","DST":"6","GMT":"6"},{"TimeZoneId":"Indian/Christmas","DST":"7","GMT":"7"},{"TimeZoneId":"Indian/Cocos","DST":"6.5","GMT":"6.5"},{"TimeZoneId":"Indian/Comoro","DST":"3","GMT":"3"},{"TimeZoneId":"Indian/Kerguelen","DST":"5","GMT":"5"},{"TimeZoneId":"Indian/Mahe","DST":"4","GMT":"4"},{"TimeZoneId":"Indian/Maldives","DST":"5","GMT":"5"},{"TimeZoneId":"Indian/Mauritius","DST":"4","GMT":"4"},{"TimeZoneId":"Indian/Mayotte","DST":"3","GMT":"3"},{"TimeZoneId":"Indian/Reunion","DST":"4","GMT":"4"},{"TimeZoneId":"Pacific/Apia","DST":"-11","GMT":"-10"},{"TimeZoneId":"Pacific/Auckland","DST":"12","GMT":"13"},{"TimeZoneId":"Pacific/Chatham","DST":"12.75","GMT":"13.75"},{"TimeZoneId":"Pacific/Easter","DST":"-6","GMT":"-5"},{"TimeZoneId":"Pacific/Efate","DST":"11","GMT":"11"},{"TimeZoneId":"Pacific/Enderbury","DST":"13","GMT":"13"},{"TimeZoneId":"Pacific/Fakaofo","DST":"-10","GMT":"-10"},{"TimeZoneId":"Pacific/Fiji","DST":"12","GMT":"13"},{"TimeZoneId":"Pacific/Funafuti","DST":"12","GMT":"12"},{"TimeZoneId":"Pacific/Galapagos","DST":"-6","GMT":"-6"},{"TimeZoneId":"Pacific/Gambier","DST":"-9","GMT":"-9"},{"TimeZoneId":"Pacific/Guadalcanal","DST":"11","GMT":"11"},{"TimeZoneId":"Pacific/Guam","DST":"10","GMT":"10"},{"TimeZoneId":"Pacific/Honolulu","DST":"-10","GMT":"-10"},{"TimeZoneId":"Pacific/Johnston","DST":"-10","GMT":"-10"},{"TimeZoneId":"Pacific/Kiritimati","DST":"14","GMT":"14"},{"TimeZoneId":"Pacific/Kosrae","DST":"11","GMT":"11"},{"TimeZoneId":"Pacific/Kwajalein","DST":"12","GMT":"12"},{"TimeZoneId":"Pacific/Majuro","DST":"12","GMT":"12"},{"TimeZoneId":"Pacific/Marquesas","DST":"-9.5","GMT":"-9.5"},{"TimeZoneId":"Pacific/Midway","DST":"-11","GMT":"-11"},{"TimeZoneId":"Pacific/Nauru","DST":"12","GMT":"12"},{"TimeZoneId":"Pacific/Niue","DST":"-11","GMT":"-11"},{"TimeZoneId":"Pacific/Norfolk","DST":"11.5","GMT":"11.5"},{"TimeZoneId":"Pacific/Noumea","DST":"11","GMT":"11"},{"TimeZoneId":"Pacific/Pago Pago","DST":"-11","GMT":"-11"},{"TimeZoneId":"Pacific/Palau","DST":"9","GMT":"9"},{"TimeZoneId":"Pacific/Pitcairn","DST":"-8","GMT":"-8"},{"TimeZoneId":"Pacific/Ponape","DST":"11","GMT":"11"},{"TimeZoneId":"Pacific/Port Moresby","DST":"10","GMT":"10"},{"TimeZoneId":"Pacific/Rarotonga","DST":"-10","GMT":"-10"},{"TimeZoneId":"Pacific/Saipan","DST":"10","GMT":"10"},{"TimeZoneId":"Pacific/Tahiti","DST":"-10","GMT":"-10"},{"TimeZoneId":"Pacific/Tarawa","DST":"12","GMT":"12"},{"TimeZoneId":"Pacific/Tongatapu","DST":"13","GMT":"13"},{"TimeZoneId":"Pacific/Truk","DST":"10","GMT":"10"},{"TimeZoneId":"Pacific/Wake","DST":"12","GMT":"12"},{"TimeZoneId":"Pacific/Wallis","DST":"12","GMT":"12"}]}';
olson = JSON.parse(olson);
var olsonKeys = Object.keys(olson);
```

Tendo um as `timezone` e o seu desfazamento horário, pode usar esta função:

```js
function gerarData(a, b) {
    var match = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < olson.result.length; i++) {
        if (olson.result[i].TimeZoneId == b) match = olson.result[i];
    }

    var clientOffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
    var timeZoneDSTOffset = parseInt(match.GMT);
    var offsetCorrection = (timeZoneDSTOffset - 3) * 60 * 60 * 1000; // *1000 porque o javascript trabalha em milisegundos
    var date = new Date(a * 1000 + offsetCorrection); 

    // função para corrigir numero de digitos para ter sempre 2
    function digitos(n) {
        return n > 9 ? "" + n : "0" + n;
    }
    // formatar a data
    var formatedDate = date.getFullYear() + '/' + 
        digitos(date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' +  // +1 porque o getMonth() começa em zero
        digitos(date.getDate()) + ' ' + 
        digitos(date.getHours()) + ':' + 
        digitos(date.getMinutes()) + ':' + 
        digitos(date.getSeconds());

    return formatedDate;
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4jppE/)

Assim, na minha demo:

```js
gerarData(1357041600, "Europe/London");     // dá "2013/01/01 10:00:00"
gerarData(1372680000, "America/Sao Paulo"); // dá "2013/07/01 09:00:00"
```

Note que esta minha sugestão não aceita `ã` e outros caracteres, mas isso você pode corrigir com [**esta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3994/como-fazer-uma-busca-ignorando-acentuacao-em-javascript) pergunta/resposta.

Este resultado é bem mais simples em PHP, você poderia criar um pedido ajax e ir buscar este valor, mas se entendí bem é isso que você não quer.

Comment: e esta variavel `olson` ? onde está declarada?

Comment: humm, está no fiddle, porém eu sugeri uma edição coloquei as zonas de tempo (`olson`) na sua resposta, pois seria o correto

Comment: @PauloRoberto, boa ideia pôr o objecto olson aqui. Obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Com JavaScript nativo, o único jeito é usar alguma solução similar ao que é sugerido [na resposta do Sergio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4487/112052).

Mas se você puder usar uma biblioteca, eu sugiro o [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/). Para trabalhar com fusos horários, também é necessário ter o [Moment Timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/).

Uma vantagem de usar esta biblioteca é que as informações de fusos horários mudam o tempo todo e é difícil manter seu código a par de todas as regras (por exemplo, no Brasil [a regra do horário de verão mudou recentemente](https://g1.globo.com/economia/noticia/horario-de-verao-comecara-em-novembro-e-nao-mais-em-outubro-a-partir-de-2018-informa-planalto.ghtml)). [Na documentação](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/use-it/) explica como manter os dados atualizados.

Com esta biblioteca, o código fica bem fácil:

```
function f(t, s) {
    return moment.tz(t * 1000, s).format('YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss');
}
```

Tive que multiplicar `t` por 1000 porque os valores que você indicou estão em segundos, mas a API trabalha com milisegundos. Para usar:

```js
function f(timestamp, timezone) {
    return moment.tz(timestamp * 1000, timezone).format('YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss');
}

console.log(f(1357041600, "America/Sao_Paulo")); // 2013/01/01 10:00:00
console.log(f(1372680000, "America/Sao_Paulo")); // 2013/07/01 09:00:00
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

Note que o segundo parâmetro é `America/Sao_Paulo`: sem acentuação e com um `_` em vez do espaço. Isso porque os nomes dos timezones seguem o [padrão da IANA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Se quiser, você pode adaptar o código para aceitar mais nomes, porém sempre mapeando para um nome válido. Para saber todos os nomes disponíveis, use a função `moment.tz.names()`, que retorna um array com todos os nomes. Ex:

```js
function f(timestamp, timezone) {
    // se o timezone não existe, usa algum valor default
    if (! moment.tz.names().includes(timezone)) {
        timezone = 'America/Sao_Paulo';
    }
    return moment.tz(timestamp * 1000, timezone).format('YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss');
}

console.log(f(1357041600, "America/Sao_Paulo")); // 2013/01/01 10:00:00
console.log(f(1372680000, "timezone invalido")); // 2013/07/01 09:00:00
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você teria de fazer download periódico da lista histórica de timezones em http://www.iana.org/time-zones, no seu servidor, interpretar este documento para um formato mais palatável em Javascript (JSON?) e carregar este documento na hora de executar a sua função "f", de modo que ela possa procurar o timezone pelo nome.

Java parece que tem esta informação também, diretamente via API, então outra saída seria carregar um applet Java que seu código Javascript então poderia consultar. Isto se você pode forçar os clientes a usar Java no browser e a solução melhor (resolver do lado servidor) não for viável.

Note que sua função "f" não precisa comunicar-se com o servidor a **cada** chamada. Basta uma vez para carregar a tabela, e se a tabela for convertida para JSON, pode ser carregada como um fonte JS a mais na página.