# Lista estática com busca usando JavaScript em vez de PHP

Tags: javascript, html, banco-de-dados, xml

No meu trabalho, criei páginas como uma lista telefônica estática para facilitar a busca dos mesmos, porém como são muitos nomes, eu gostaria de criar um campo de pesquisa, porém não é possível fazer isso sem código dinâmico e banco de dados. É possível fazer isso com JavaScript com os dados salvos em um XML?.

O interesse não é segurança e nada, visto que é uma página pra facilitar a busca. Não uso o PHP porque na minha empresa não é permitida a instalação de programas (Apache, etc)  nas máquinas. Minha dúvida é saber se é possível fazer isso com XML e JavaScript.

Comment: Eu deixaria os dados numa variável javascript mesmo, um num json. XML só vai complicar as coisas. Tendo os dados, a parte chata será lidar com caracteres acentuados na busca. Ver esta pergunta relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3994/como-fazer-uma-busca-ignorando-acentuacao-em-javascript

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Não é necessário ter nenhuma tecnologia no servidor. É perfeitamente possível fazer uma busca simples com Javascript.

## Busca só com jQuery

Fiz um exemplo usando jQuery. A primeira coisa é ter uma tabela com os nomes e os telefones. No meu exemplo fiz assim:

```html
<table id="lista">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><div>Nome</div><div><input id="filtro-nome"/></div></th>
            <th>Telefone</th>
            <th>Ramal</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Ana</td>
            <td>3333-3333</td>
            <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>João</td>
            <td>3333-3333</td>
            <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Luiz</td>
            <td>3333-3333</td>
            <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mário</td>
            <td>3333-3333</td>
            <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Rodrigo</td>
            <td>3333-3333</td>
            <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Silvana</td>
            <td>3333-3333</td>
            <td>123</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Note que coloquei um campo para busca no cabeçalho.

Com isso podemos fazer um script que executa quando o campo de filtro é alterado. Para cada linha ele verifica se o filtro corresponde com o nome e oculta ou exibe a linha conforme o caso. Considere o código abaixo:

```js
$('#filtro-nome').keyup(function() {
    var nomeFiltro = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('table tbody').find('tr').each(function() {
        var conteudoCelula = $(this).find('td:first').text();
        var corresponde = conteudoCelula.toLowerCase().indexOf(nomeFiltro) >= 0;
        $(this).css('display', corresponde ? '' : 'none');
    });
});
```

### [Demo no jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utluiz/suCtE/)

---

## Busca só com Javascript "puro"

Como você não pode instalar um servidor, pode ser mais fácil distribuir o HTML sem nenhuma dependência. Pensando nisso, fiz uma versão que não depende de uma biblioteca como o jQuery;

```js
var filtro = document.getElementById('filtro-nome');
var tabela = document.getElementById('lista');
filtro.onkeyup = function() {
    var nomeFiltro = filtro.value;
    for (var i = 1; i < tabela.rows.length; i++) {
        var conteudoCelula = tabela.rows[i].cells[0].innerText;
        var corresponde = conteudoCelula.toLowerCase().indexOf(nomeFiltro) >= 0;
        tabela.rows[i].style.display = corresponde ? '' : 'none';
    }
};
```

### [Demo no jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utluiz/YBLu6/)

Answer (score 1):

Obrigado à todos pelas informações! Com o conteúdo repassado, eu pude criar a seguinte estrutura:

```
<table id="lista">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th><div>Nome</div><div><input id="filtro-nome"/></div></th>
        <th>Telefone</th>
        <th>Ramal</th>
        <th>Celular</th>
        <th><div>Email</div><div><input id="filtro-email"/></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Não saber número</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ocupado</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>TI - Sala Servidores - CPD</td>
        <td>*** ****-****</td>
        <td>****</td>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>-</td>
    </tr>
```

...

E o javascript ficou assim:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload=function(){

//para nomes
var filtro = document.getElementById('filtro-nome');
var tabela = document.getElementById('lista');
filtro.onkeyup = function() {
    var nomeFiltro = filtro.value;
    for (var i = 1; i < tabela.rows.length; i++) {
        var conteudoCelula = tabela.rows[i].cells[0].innerText;
        var corresponde = conteudoCelula.toLowerCase().indexOf(nomeFiltro) >= 0;
        tabela.rows[i].style.display = corresponde ? '' : 'none';
    }
};

//para email
var filtro2 = document.getElementById('filtro-email');
var tabela2 = document.getElementById('lista');
filtro2.onkeyup = function() {
    var nomeFiltro = filtro2.value;
    for (var i = 1; i < tabela2.rows.length; i++) {
        var conteudoCelula = tabela2.rows[i].cells[0].innerText;
        var corresponde = conteudoCelula.toLowerCase().indexOf(nomeFiltro) >= 0;
        tabela2.rows[i].style.display = corresponde ? '' : 'none';
    }
};

}

</script>
```

Com isso, pude criar uma lista telefônica extensa com uma pesquisa. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Esse seu código é perfeito para o que eu preciso, só que tem um porém eu preciso disso com DIV e outras tags, tentei modificar o que vc fez, mas sem sucesso, tem como ajudar?

Comment: Olá, a ideia era pesquisar também pelo email? tentei usar o exemplo e a busca só funciona com o nome. Queria fazer a mesma pesquisa ora por nome ora por email. Agradeço se puder ajudar.

Comment: Oi! Em tese, ele também funciona para email, mas apenas sendo feito pelo outro campo de texto que fiz nesse documento. Você queria apenas um campo de texto para consultar os dois?