# Busca usando apenas JavaScript em todos campos da tabela

Tags: javascript, html, algoritmo-de-busca, tabela-html

O **script** que vou postar logo abaixo copiei da resposta dessa pergunta:
[Lista estática com busca usando JavaScript em vez de PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8555/lista-est%c3%a1tica-com-busca-usando-javascript-em-vez-de-php/9010#9010), que foi feita aqui na comunidade.

```
    window.onload=function(){
    var filtro = document.getElementById('filtro-nome');
    var tabela = document.getElementById('lista');
    filtro.onkeyup = function() {
        var nomeFiltro = filtro.value;
        for (var i = 1; i < tabela.rows.length; i++) {
            var conteudoCelula = tabela.rows[i].cells[0].innerText;
            var corresponde = conteudoCelula.toLowerCase().indexOf(nomeFiltro) >= 0;
            tabela.rows[i].style.display = corresponde ? '' : 'none';
        }
    }
}
```

**Direto ao assunto!** Preciso que busque todos os nomes de livros da tabela (66 livros), atendendo os critérios postei apenas parte do código logo abaixo, porem só está buscando o primeiro nome, acho que é porque o script busca a linha (rows), e eu não sei como fazer para buscar nos outros campos, se eu digito Juízes ou Rute por exemplo... não busca! Pode ver [aqui](https://mlssystem.github.io/bibliasagrada.github.io/) se quiser.

```
        <table id="lista" class="degrade-tbl">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><div>Pesquisa</div><div><input id="filtro-nome"/></div>
        </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="">Gênesis</a></td>
                    <td><a href="">Êxodo</a></td>
                    <td><a href="">Levítico</a></td>
                    <td><a href="">Números</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="">Deuteronômio</a></td>
                    <td><a href="">Josué</a></td>
                    <td><a href="">Juízes</a></td>
                    <td><a href="">Rute</a></td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Encontrei esse [script](http://www.adrianomeira.com/blog/pesquisando-dados-dentro-de-uma-tabela-usando-jquery-quick-search-table-jquery) em Jquery, mas no GitHub só permite HTML, CSS, Java Script. Alguém poderia me ajudar por gentileza?

Desde já agradeço - Obrigado!

*Meu projeto está no GitHub como: [bibliasagrada](https://bibliasagrada.github.io/), caso queiram dar uma olhada!*

Não se esqueçam que JESUS voltará para buscar todos aqueles que creem! Meditem na palavra de Jesus no evangelho de [João capitulo 14](https://bibliasagrada.github.io/novo_testamento/joao/joao-14.html).

Fiquem com Deus!

PAZ!

Comment: De onde vêm as palavras a procurar? Tens um `<input>` no HTML ou vem do JavaScript?

Comment: Bom dia @Sergio. As palavras vem da pagina index no próprio HTML e o <input> está na quarta linha do segundo código. Vem do HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes fazer isso assim:

```js
const input = document.getElementById('filtro-nome');
const trs = [...document.querySelectorAll('#lista tbody tr')];

input.addEventListener('input', () => {
  const search = input.value.toLowerCase();
  trs.forEach(el => {
    const matches = el.textContent.toLowerCase().includes(search);
    el.style.display = matches ? 'block' : 'none';
  });
});
```

```html
<table id="lista" class="degrade-tbl">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div>Pesquisa</div>
        <div><input id="filtro-nome" /></div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="">Gênesis</a></td>
      <td><a href="">Êxodo</a></td>
      <td><a href="">Levítico</a></td>
      <td><a href="">Números</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="">Deuteronômio</a></td>
      <td><a href="">Josué</a></td>
      <td><a href="">Juízes</a></td>
      <td><a href="">Rute</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Você é uma benção meu irmão. Deus te abençoe! Muito obrigado de coração. Em relação a acentuação @Sergio, por exemplo Gênesis tem o acento circunflexo no 'e', se eu não colocar não vai aparecer. Daria muito trabalho pra ignorar, e fazer a busca mesmo se não acentuar?

Comment: @Marcus em JavaScript isso é meio dificil. Dá uma olhada aqui para inspiração: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/148180/129