# Como ordenar array de strings desconsiderando acentos?

Tags: javascript, array

Se eu tiver um array como o seguinte:

```
exemplo = ["Árvore", "Casa", "Computador", "É", "Poste", "Pássaro", "Índia", "Ar", "Ásia"]
```

O `exemplo.sort()` considera a acentuação das palavras para ordenar, colocando as acentuadas por último:

```
exemplo.sort()
["Ar", "Casa", "Computador", "Poste", "Pássaro", "Árvore", "Ásia", "É", "Índia"]
```

Como fazer com que o array seja ordenado desconsiderando os acentos?

Comment: Relacionado (mas não exatamente duplicata): http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3994/como-fazer-uma-busca-ignorando-acentuacao-em-javascript

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Utilize o localeCompare, conforme a documentação encontrada aqui:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

```
var items = ["Cátodo", "caule", "casca"];
items.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.localeCompare(b);
});
```

O resultado é equivalente a:

```
[ "casca", "Cátodo", "caule" ]
```

Comment: Bem mais simples do que imaginava! Já estava pensando em usar regex.

Comment: Nossa, ia dar um trabalho ein! rsrsrs