# Como ordenar uma array de objetos com array.sort()

Tags: javascript

Teria como eu especificar para o método `array.sort();` como é a forma de ordenação? Por exemplo, eu tenho um array de objetos pessoa, e pessoa tem nome e número eu queria que a ordenação fosse feita pelo nome. Como eu iria especificar isso para o meu método sort?

Comment: O método sort aceita uma função, se explicares o que queres fazer (dando exemplos) podemos ajudar a ajudtar essa função

Answer (score 29, accepted):

O método `sort` aceita como parâmetro [opcional] uma função com dois parâmetros - dois objetos a serem comparados pelo algoritmo de ordenação. Essa função deve retornar um número negativo se o primeiro objeto é menor que o segundo, um número positivo se o segundo é menor que o primeiro, e zero se ambos são iguais.

Se você quer comparar pelo nome da pessoa (que presumo ser uma string), um meio é comparar esses atributos e retornar a valor correspondente:

```
pessoas.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a.nome < b.nome ? -1 : a.nome > b.nome ? 1 : 0;
});
```

Answer (score 14):

O método `.sort()` aceita uma função. Essa função vai influênciar a posição final através do que essa mesma função retorna.

```
function compare(a, b) {
  if (se a fôr menor que b) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a fôr maior que b) {
    return 1;
  }
  // são idênticos
  return 0;
}
```

Ou seja, a função aceita dois parametros aos quais são atribuídos elementos da array a ser comparados. Se a função der `return` maior que `0`, então o elemento `b` deve "passar à frente" do elemento `a`.

Exemplo:

```
[0, 20, 3, 4].sort(function compare(a, b) {
    if (a < b) return -1;
    if (a > b) return 1;
    return 0;
})
// dá [0, 3, 4, 20]
```

Se comparar-mos o tamanho de strings um exemplo seria:

```
['muito longo', 'curto', 'médio'].sort(function compare(a, b) {
    if (a.length < b.length) return -1;
    if (a.length > b.length) return 1;
    return 0;
})
// dá ["curto", "médio", "muito longo"]
```

Ou seja, se encontrares uma funcionalidade de comparar os elementos da array que tens podes ordena-la seguindo esta lógica.

Answer (score 10):

A solução mais simples é passar uma função ao método `sort` da array, fazendo manualmente a comparação entre as propriedades dos objetos que contenham os nomes. O `sort` usa essa função para comparar pares de valores, e espera que ela retorne `0` para strings iguais ou equivalentes, um número positivo se o primeiro valor for maior que o segundo, ou um número negativo se o segundo for maior.

```
var pessoas = [{
    nome: "Mariana"
}, {
    nome: "Maria"
}, {
    nome: "Ana"
}];

pessoas.sort(function(a,b) {
    if(a.nome < b.nome) return -1;
    if(a.nome > b.nome) return 1;
    return 0;
});
```

Mas atenção às limitações desse método:

- Esse método diferencia maiúsculas de minúsculas (`'A' < 'a'`). Isso pode ser resolvido convertendo-se tudo para maiúsculas ou minúsculas antes de comparar.
- Esse método considera caracteres acentuados como maiores que os demais (por exemplo, `'Á' > 'z'`). Isso pode ser resolvido [substituindo alguns caracteres](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3995/74) antes de comparar.

Uma solução melhor para resolver o problema dos acentos, partindo do princípio de que os browsers/sistemas operacionais de quem está executando o script estejam configurados para português:

```
pessoas.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a.localeCompare(b);
});
```

Fonte: [Resposta do Rui Pimentel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16500/74) a *[Como ordenar array de strings desconsiderando acentos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16496/como-ordenar-array-de-strings-desconsiderando-acentos)*.

Esse método [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) está disponível em qualquer string, e também aceita um segundo argumento que seria a string de *locale* que você quer usar (por exemplo, `"pt-BR"`). Mas tem questões de compatibilidade, segundo a MDN.

Answer (score 10):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
var pessoas = [ 
    { nome: 'Joao', num: 1     },
    { nome: 'Maria', num: 2     },
    { nome: 'Fulano', num: 3    }
    ];

function compare(a,b) {
  if (a.nome < b.nome)
     return -1;
  if (a.nome > b.nome)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}

pessoas.sort(compare);
```

Caso queira ordenar por outro atributo é só modificar na função `compare`.

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sorting-objects-in-an-array-by-a-field-value-in-javascript)

Answer (score 5):

Resumindo com um pouco de cada:

```
users = [
    {nome: "Thiago"},
    {nome: "thiago"},
    {nome: "Marcos"},
    {nome: "thiago"},
    {nome: "Ana"}
]

namesOrder(arrayObj){
    return arrayObj.sort(function(objA,objB) {
      a = aobjA.nome.toLowerCase().replace(/[àáâãäå]/,"a").replace(/[èéêë]/,"e").replace(/[ìíîï]/,"i").replace(/[òóôõö]/,"o").replace(/[ùúûü]/,"u").replace(/[ç]/,"c").replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi,'')
      b = objB.nome.toLowerCase().replace(/[àáâãäå]/,"a").replace(/[èéêë]/,"e").replace(/[ìíîï]/,"i").replace(/[òóôõö]/,"o").replace(/[ùúûü]/,"u").replace(/[ç]/,"c").replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi,'')
      return a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0;
    })
  }

namesOrder(users)
```

Vale salientar que o lowercase e os replace não serão aplicados no objeto final, apenas no objeto de comparação.