# Ordenando array de objetos por nome

Tags: javascript

Bom estou com um array de objetos e preciso ordena-lo pelo nome.
Meu array a seguir:

```
COD_IDENT_PESSO: "120151202162147"
FLG_IDENT_PRESE: "M"
FLG_STATU_PESSO: "A"
TXT_NOMEX_PESSO: "Renan Rodrigues Moraes"

COD_IDENT_PESSO: "120151202162542"
FLG_IDENT_PRESE: "L"
FLG_STATU_PESSO: "A"
TXT_NOMEX_PESSO: "Pedro Algusto"

COD_IDENT_PESSO: "120151202162836"
FLG_IDENT_PRESE: "M"
FLG_STATU_PESSO: "A"
TXT_NOMEX_PESSO: "Andre Medeiros"

COD_IDENT_PESSO: "120151202162837"
FLG_IDENT_PRESE: "M"
FLG_STATU_PESSO: "A"
TXT_NOMEX_PESSO: "Sousa Carvalho"

COD_IDENT_PESSO: "1151206095050177"
FLG_IDENT_PRESE: "L"
FLG_STATU_PESSO: "A"
TXT_NOMEX_PESSO: "Membro Sinc"

COD_IDENT_PESSO: "1151209082951928"
FLG_IDENT_PRESE: "M"
FLG_STATU_PESSO: "A"
TXT_NOMEX_PESSO: "55555"
```

Meu código responsável por ordenar:

```
for(var i = 0; i < arrayVelho.length; i++){
   if(arrayVelho[i].TXT_NOMEX_PESSO < nome){
       nome = arrayVelho[i].TXT_NOMEX_PESSO;
       arrayNovo = arrayVelho[i];
       arrayVelho[i].pop();
    }
}
```

Porém esta logica que utilizei não esta funcionando, como fazer ?

Comment: opa aqui pode te ajudar, basta adaptar. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100068/ordenando-um-array-de-objetos-por-data/100076#100076

Comment: Aqui tem outra resposta também. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/46600/como-ordenar-uma-array-de-objetos-com-array-sort

Comment: Pessoal muito obrigado, para mim tinha logica diferente, porem deu certinho com que eu queria.

Comment: Encontrou uma resposta para sua pergunta?

Comment: Sim muito obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Para ordenar objetos use o a função `sort()`, [**aqui tem mais informações**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

```
   arrayVelho.sort(function(a,b) {
        if(a.TXT_NOMEX_PESSO < b.TXT_NOMEX_PESSO) return -1;
        if(a.TXT_NOMEX_PESSO > b.TXT_NOMEX_PESSO) return 1;
        return 0;
    });

    for(var i = 0; i < arrayVelho.length; i++){
       if(arrayVelho[i].TXT_NOMEX_PESSO < nome){
           nome = arrayVelho[i].TXT_NOMEX_PESSO;
           arrayNovo = arrayVelho[i];
           arrayVelho[i].pop();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[RESPOSTA  ORIGINAL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/100076/25415).

Veja Funcionando.

```js
    var objeto = [ 
    { data : new Date('11-30-2015'), nome: 'Marconi', telefone:'32486745425'},
    { data : new Date('11-31-2015'), nome: 'Marcos', telefone:'32486745425'},
    { data : new Date('11-25-2015'), nome: 'B', telefone:'32486745425'},
    { data : new Date('11-27-2015'), nome: 'Testes', telefone:'32486745425'},
];
    
function compare(a,b) {
  return a.nome < b.nome;
}

console.log(objeto.sort(compare));
```