# indexOf com expressão regular usando variável

Tags: javascript, regex

Eu utilizo o indexOf para verificar se uma string contém um determinado texto. Porém isso é case sensitive e sensivel também a acentos.

Teria alguma maneira de por exemplo eu encontrar esses registros no caso de inserir na busca qualquer um deles a seguir?:

- joao
- Joao
- jOao
- joão
- João

Imagino que com expressão regular eu poderia conseguir, mas não entendo muito bem ainda o funcionamento delas. Ainda mais quando se trata de uma variável.

Meu código esta assim:

```
var textoBusca = $("#campoBusca").val();

if(meuTexto.indexOf(textoBusca) != -1){
    alert("Foram encontrados registros");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existem diferentes formas de fazer isso e vai depender do seu objetivo.

Primeiro, para ignorar os acentos você pode usar as soluções [desta questão indicada pelo mgibsonbr](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3994/como-fazer-uma-busca-ignorando-acentua%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-javascript) para remover a acentuação tanto do texto de pesquisa e do que será pesquisado.

Em seguida, você pode optar por usar a função [`search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) para realizar uma busca *case-insensitive* usando Regex.

Outra alternativa, sem uso de Regex, seria converter todos os textos para letras [maiúsculas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) ou [minúsculas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) e usar o `indexOf` mesmo.

Finalmente, se a ideia for buscar apenas palavras inteiras em um texto que não é muito grande, ainda há a possibilidade de quebrar o texto original em palavras e comparar uma a uma usando a função [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare). Esta função possui parâmetros que ignoram acentuação e *case*.

Por exemplo, considere os seguintes comandos:

```
console.log('á'.localeCompare('a', 'br', { sensitivity: 'base' })); 
console.log('Ã'.localeCompare('a', 'br', { sensitivity: 'base' }));
```

Ambos retornam `0` (zero) porque consideram as letras iguais.