# replace com expressão regular (regex) ignorando acentos

Tags: regex, asp

Recentemente alterei as url amigaveis, devido a isso a querystryng usada pra buscas foi filtrada pra sem acentos. Com relação as consultas ao banco de dados independente de a palavra ter acento ou não está sendo encontrada. Mas eu costumava dar um replace para destacar as palavras buscadas

```
    Replace (texto, palavra,"<b>" & palavra & "</b>"
```

Resumindo, como posso fazer para usar uma `ereg_replace()` para ignorar acentos. Exemplo:

```
    Texto="Este é um filme de Ação e tem muita ação. "
    Palavra="acao"
    texto=Ereg_replace(condição_RegEx_que_ignora_Acentos-e-case, texto, palavra,"<b>"& palavra & "</b>")
    'Resultado q preciso:
    "Este é um filme de <b>Ação</b> e tem muita <b>ação</b>."
```

Desde já agradeço a atenção

@EDITE pra explicar melhor:

eu tenho uma palavra que está sem acento vindo da querystring, uma busca: exemplo: toquio
Preciso fazer uma substituição para destacar essa palavra no texto, estando ou não acentuada.
Então um texto com **toquio** ou **Toquio** ou **Tóquio** ou **tóquio** 
que foi encontrada pelo termo de pesquisa: **toquio** ou **Toquio** ou **Tóquio** ou **tóquio**
precisa ser substituida por ela mesma adicionada da tag `<b>...</b>`
por tanto qualquer texto com a palavra: **toquio** ou **Toquio** ou **Tóquio** ou **tóquio** deve ficar com ela mesma adicionada da tag, assim:

```
era assim: Fui pra Toquio.
precisa ficar assim: Fui pra <b>Toquio</b>.

mas se for assim: Fui pra Tóquio.
precisa ficar assim: Fui pra <b>Tóquio</b>.

ou ainda: Fui pra tóquio.
precisa ficar assim: Fui pra <b>tóquio</b>.

ou ainda: Fui pra toquio.
precisa ficar assim: Fui pra <b>toquio</b>.
```

isso independente se o usuário digitou na busca **toquio** ou **Toquio** ou **Tóquio** ou **tóquio**

ficou melhor @david

Comment: Acredito que esteja meio confuso, pelo que entendi, você precisa de um algoritmo que ao encontrar a palavra no texto adicione as tags <b> </b> certo?

Comment: isso. independente de case (maiúscula ou minuscula) e acentos.. Exatamente como o exemplo que coloquei

Comment: É que ficou confuso, o que você pediu "ignorar acentos", e no caso não seria isso, teria como reformular sua pergunta?

Comment: Não conheço asp, mas provavelmente o `ereg_replace` aceita grupos de captura, então se você passar a regex `"(" & padrao & ")"` como primeiro argumento, a substituição pode ser `"<b>$1</b>"` e ele vai inserir a palavra encontrada no resultado (e não o padrão). Resta então saber como fazer esse padrão pra ignorar acentos e capitalização.

Comment: @david mas é exatamente isso que eu quero: trocar uma palavra; tenha ela acento ou não; pela mesma palavras, mantendo se tinha acento ou não, adicionando uma tag, apenas isso. Creio q o termo q usei está certo e o exemplo claro

Comment: @mgibsonbr, é mais ou menos isso mesmo, eu achei uma função pra RegEx em asp mas não sei ao certo como fazer uma condição para atender a isso, achei necessidade parecida no stackoverflow americano mas está em php e não entendi direito, pq já não sei mto de php em ingles ainda... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477213/regex-to-ignore-accents-php

Comment: Já eu não sei asp... :( Dá uma olhada [nessa outra pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3994/215) (pra JavaScript) - em particular [essa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3997/215) -  e vê se te dá uma luz. A ideia é você substituir cada letra no padrão por um conjunto de caracteres "semelhantes", antes de usar no `ereg_replace`. Então, se sua palavra é `acao`, sua regex final seria `[aAáÁâÂàÀãÃ][cCçÇ][aAáÁâÂàÀãÃ][oOóÓôÔòÒõÕ]`. Você precisaria criar uma função pra a partir do termo de busca criar essa regex.

Comment: P.S. Só esclarece uma coisa: você está usando ASP clássico mesmo, não ASP.Net, certo?

Comment: @mgibsonbr, sim asp classico

Comment: @mgibsonbr, eu tinha achado essa pagina, mas não consegui converter numa função asp parecida. Nessa página https://github.com/chiquitto/FuncoesASP/blob/master/lb.string.asp tem a função ereg_replace, que acredito fazer isso que estou precisando, mas não sei exatamente como ficaria seu uso, principalmente o pattern pra ele funcionar fazendo isso que preciso

Comment: @David editei para explicar mais detalhadamente, veja se ficou claro pra ti.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Nota: não conheço muito bem ASP, vou responder com a lógica proposta, mas o código pode não estar 100% correto.

Sugiro a partir do termo de busca você criar uma regex para ele, substituindo cada letra da palavra por um intervalo contendo todas as variações da letra (maiúsculas/minúsculas/acentuadas), e então usar essa regex no `Ereg_replace`.

```
function CriarRegex(palavra)
    palavra = eregi_replace("a", "[aAáÁâÂàÀäÄãÃ]", palavra)
    palavra = eregi_replace("e", "[eEéÉêÊèÈëË]", palavra)
    palavra = eregi_replace("i", "[iIíÍîÎìÌïÏ]", palavra)
    palavra = eregi_replace("o", "[oOóÓôÔòÒöÖõÕ]", palavra)
    palavra = eregi_replace("u", "[uUúÚûÛùÙüÜ]", palavra)
    palavra = eregi_replace("c", "[cCçÇ]", palavra)
    CriarRegex= "(" & palavra & ")"
End Function
```

(O `eregi_replace` deve desconsiderar maiúsculas/minúsculas, entretanto como não sei se isso vale também pra palavras acentuadas, usei todas as combinações no código acima.)

Na hora de usar, mande substuir o texto pelo resultado do primeiro grupo de captura, assim a palavra inserida no final será a mesma palavra encontrada no texto, e não o termo de busca:

```
Texto="Este é um filme de Ação e tem muita ação. "
Palavra="acao"
Regex = CriarRegex(Palavra)
texto=eregi_replace(Regex, "<b>$1</b>", texto)
```

A propósito, o código acima vai destacar também coisas como "cri**ação**" - o que pode ou não ser o que você quer. Se só quiser destacar palavras inteiras, use um "delimitador de palavras" (*word boundary*) na sua regex (se suportado pela [biblioteca que mencionou](https://github.com/chiquitto/FuncoesASP/blob/master/lb.string.asp)):

```
    CriarRegex= "(\b" & palavra & "\b)"
    CriarRegex= "(\\b" & palavra & "\\b)"
```

(não sei se em ASP você precisa "escapar" a barra invertida ou não, então postei as duas variações)

Comment: Tá certo que esse tipo de coisa provavelmente é caso de substituição de string e não RegEx, mas como a pergunta pede assim, está bem resolvido. +1

Comment: @Bacco Não sei, pra mim é caso de regex mesmo. Pois o AP quer identificar no texto uma palavra "parecida" com o termo de busca, e substituir por algo que é uma função da palavra encontrada (e não do termo buscado). Me parece uma aplicação própria de regex. Ou você se refere à função `CriarRegex` em si? (que *talvez* pudesse ser melhor feita usando um loop)

Comment: @mgibsonbr é bem isso mesmo. Mas acho q  precisa de alguns ajustes pra asp ainda. principalmente no final onde está "<b>$1</b>" acho q em asp será considerado tudo apenas como texto literal

Comment: @mgibsonbr imagino que uma tabela simples de substituição +  um loop único faça tudo bem melhor que RegEx, considerando que o charset envolvido é pequeno. Mas vai muito de cada um o tipo de implementação. Eu uso uma coisa parecida com isso pra fazer busca que ignora acentos no SQLite, por uma questão de performance.

Comment: @SuperMax Esse `$1` é uma referência ao primeiro grupo de captura. É responsabilidade da biblioteca de regex - e não da linguagem em si - substituir isso pela palavra real. E eu vejo que ASP dá suporte a isso, veja na biblioteca que você indicou, há vários exemplos de substituições desse tipo ao longo do código. (em outras palavras, é pra ser um texto literal mesmo)

Comment: @mgibsonbr, cara, demais, funcionou de primeira. Muitíssimo obrigado, era isso mesmo. E tbm concordo contigo, era uma questão de RegEx e não apenas replace. No caso seria um RegEx dentro de um replace. Mas obrigado não só pela excelente resposta como a plena compreensão da mesma e sua resolução. Gde abraço e ótimo Natal

Comment: Boa ideia, apesar de que na consulta sql já estar fazendo esse filtro corretamente pode realmente ocorrer alguma situação de repente de ter a palavra "votação" no meio do contexto, não havia atentado para isso, mas no caso a sua solução com uma "\"b apenas já resolve isso. Mais um muito obrigado

Comment: Surgiu um problema para delimitar a palavra inteira. Qdo o acento é na primeira ou na última letra ai não está pegando. Veja o exemplo resumido http://www.regexr.com/3cfp7

Comment: Muito estranho mesmo... Não sei o que está causando isso, mas consegui um resultado semelhante usando *lookarounds*: `(?<!\w)([eé]t[eé]st[eé])(?!\w)`. O problema é que eles (principalmente o *lookbehind*) não são suportados por todas as engines de regex. O regexr.com por exemplo aceitou o *lookahead* mas não o *lookbehind*. O rubular [aceitou ambos](http://rubular.com/r/5WCDXfKhC4). Teria que testar na sua plataforma e ver se funciona. P.S. Essa regex não é perfeita, um `áéteste` ou `etesteá` por exemplo não deveria ser casado mas é.

Comment: Obrigado mais uma vez pelo seu retorno. Não funcionou pra mim, mas dei uma modificada assim: (^\b|\s|-)([eé]t[eé]st[eé])(?!\w) http://www.regexr.com/3cfr6 e alterei o replace para: "$1<b>$2</b>". Resolveu quase tudo (acho) a única exceção que percebi até o momento foi a segunda q vc citou: etesteá. Mesmo se não tiver solução acho que dá pra conviver com isso.

Comment: @SuperMax A dificuldade é que `\w` não casa caracteres acentuados, então você teria que substituir ele pela lista completa de caracteres. Por exemplo, se você substituir o último `(?!\w)` por `(?![\wé])` ele deixa de casar as duas últimas palavras que sobraram. Teria então que usar tudo para pegar o que falta: `(?![\wáâàäãÁ...ÜçÇ])`. A propósito, seu sistema suporta quantificadores possessivos? Uma maneira mais "segura" de contornar a falta dos *lookarounds* seria fazendo `([^\wá...Ç]?+)(regex)([^\wá...Ç]?+)` para `$1<b>$2</b>$3` (mas o `?+` tem que ser possessivo pra funcionar, não basta `?`)

Comment: ?+ não rodou, dá erro, Mas  (^|!\b|\s|-)([eé]t[eé]st[eé])([^\wááâàäãéêèëíîìïóôòöõúûùüç-]|$) Resolveu praticamente tudo; a única exceção ficou para qdo tiver a palavra repedida logo ao lado, tipo: bla bla eteste eteste bla bla. Mas acho pouco provável ocorrer isso de fato, espero apenas que qdo tiver suas palavras; eteste e ateste não ocorra isso, acho que não irá ocorrer. Tb não consegui pegar se estiver entre aspas: "eteste". mas tb não teria mtas ocorrências pra essa situação. Eu só me pergunto se o tamanho que ficou pode atrapalhar com a performance? Obrigado mais uma vez.

Comment: @SuperMax Nesse caso não, pois a regex consome um caractere por vez e não há *backtracking*. Mesmo ela sendo "comprida" a performance deve ser boa.