# Como fazer o Chosen ignorar acentos na busca?

Tags: javascript, chosen-jquery-plugin

Estou utilizando o [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) em meus formulários, mas gostaria que ele ignorasse os acentos ao filtrar.

Por exemplo: Em uma listagem de cidades, filtra a corretamente para:

**- áfrica**

Porém não filtra para (pois as palavras se diferenciam pelo acento):

**- africa**

No GitHub do projeto, já há discussões sobre isso desde 12/03/2012 (https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/536), mas ainda não implementaram isso no código oficial.

Lendo as discussões existentes, achei este exemplo funcional, postado pelo [@felpasl](https://github.com/felpasl):

- Exemplo funcionando: http://fiddle.jshell.net/whqb5/1/

Porém, pretendo implementar o seu funcionamento, porém sem alterar os códigos fontes originais, para minimizar complicações futuras ao atualizar o código a partir do repositório oficial.

Pensei em substituir o método, externamente, mas não estou conseguindo fazer. Abaixo o código que tentei, para substituir o método...

```
var Chosen = $('#campo_select_com_chosen').chosen();
Chosen.prototype.search_string_match = function (search_string, regex) {
    alert('Método substituído com sucesso');
};
```

Mas obtenho este erro:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'search_string_match' of undefined

Minha dificuldade está em como substituir um método da lib que estou utilizando sem alterar os fontes da mesma. Se fosse em PHP eu iria herdar a classe e substituir o método... mas em JavaScript não sei como fazer.

Alguém poderia me ajudar sobre como fazer esta implementação, tipo PlugIn, no Chosen?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3994/como-fazer-uma-busca-ignorando-acentuação-em-javascript

Comment: @bfavaretto mais uma vez agradeço o seu apoio. Minha dificuldade está em como substituir um método da lib que estou utilizando sem alterar os fontes da mesma. Se fosse em PHP eu iria herdar a classe e substituir o método... mas em JavaScript não sei como fazer.

Comment: parece que não tem como mesmo, o Chosen não expõe nada pra você alterar de fora (pelo menos pelo código que está no seu jsfiddle).

Answer (score 2):

No StackOverflow em inglês teve uma pergunta similar, e existe uma issue aberta no GitHub solicitando esta alteração.

Nesta issue tem vários usuários colocando formas de alterar o código, uma delas postadas nesta resposta do Stack e já deve resolver seu problema.

Está no JSFiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/whqb5/1/
Deve funcionar importando logo abaixo do Chosen por conta dos prototypes.

Ou se quiser uma solução mais direta, nas últimas respostas na Issue o usuário Hanoii criou uma versão do Chosen que é capaz de fazer esse tipo de pesquisa:
https://github.com/hanoii/chosen/releases

**Pergunta**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31960166/chosen-search-accented-words
**Issue**: https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/536

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção, ma como disse na pergunta, estou procurando uma forma de implantação sem alterações nos fontes do Chosen.

Comment: Ah sim, coloquei na edição e tinha esquecido.

Então é como @bfavaretto disse, não há nada para mexer.
O arquivo é uma função direto que se chama logo ao fim, não há nem mesmo nome.

Pra usar o prototype se não me engano você teria que ter um objeto. Mas mesmo assim, você teria que mexer no código pra criar uma classe e instanciar o Chosen (o que não seria algo tão fácil).