# Como filtrar uma lista em vue com resposta ignorando acentos e maiúsculo/minúsculo?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue.js-2

Estou fazendo um filtro de uma lista pelo nome, ele funciona, porém se tenho um nome cadastrado como Hígor, o filtro não funciona quando escrevo higor.

```
  computed: {
    filtered: function () {
      const search = this.configs.search
      const users = _.orderBy(this.users, this.configs.orderBy, this.configs.order)

      if (_.isEmpty(search)) {
        return users;
      }

      return _.filter(users, user => user.name.indexOf(search) >= 0)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiz uma junção dessa resposta [Como fazer uma busca ignorando acentuação em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3994/como-fazer-uma-busca-ignorando-acentua%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-javascript), para normalizar os texto acentuados (removendo os acentos) e também colocando os valores todos em caixa baixa, e isso resultou em um exemplo minimo:

```js
var vm = new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 data: {
  title: 'Pesquisa',
  items: [
   {id: 1, name:'Paul Lima'},
   {id: 2, name:'souza Cruz'},
   {id: 3, name:'Adael cruz'},
   {id: 4, name:'Pául lima'},
   {id: 5, name:'Pâul cruz'},
   {id: 6, name:'Sôuza Cruz'},
   {id: 6, name:'Cruz adael'}
  ]
 },
 methods: {
   nameFilter: function(item) {
  if (!this.searchText || this.searchText === '') {
   return true;
  }
  var n = this.prepareNameFilter(item.name);
  var s = this.prepareNameFilter(this.searchText);         
  return n.includes(s);
   },
   prepareNameFilter: function replaceSpecialChars(str) {
  if (!str) return '';       
  str = str.toLowerCase();
  str = str.replace(/[aáàãäâ]/,'a');
  str = str.replace(/[eéèëê]/,'e');
  str = str.replace(/[iíìïî]/,'i');
  str = str.replace(/[oóòõöô]/,'o');
  str = str.replace(/[uúùüû]/,'u');
  return str; 
   }
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/0.12.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
 {{title}}
 <br />
 <input type="text" v-model="searchText"/>
 <br />
 <ul>
  <li v-repeat="items | filterBy nameFilter">
   {{id}} {{name}}
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

*Como você não postou um exemplo minimo do seu código, fica um pouco complicado refletir no que foi feito, então, esse exemplo pode te ajudar a adaptar no seu código.*

Answer (score 0):

Muito obrigada, funcionou pra mim. Ficou assim:

```js
    filtered: function () {
      const search = this.configs.search
      const users = _.orderBy(this.users, this.configs.orderBy, this.configs.order)

      if (_.isEmpty(search)) {
        return users
      }
      
      function replaceSpecialChars(str) {
        if (!str) return ''
        str = str.toString()
        str = str.replace(/[aáàãäâ]/,'a')
        str = str.replace(/[eéèëê]/,'e')
        str = str.replace(/[iíìïî]/,'i')
        str = str.replace(/[oóòõöô]/,'o')
        str = str.replace(/[uúùüû]/,'u')
        return str 
      }

      return _.filter(users, user => replaceSpecialChars(user.name.toLowerCase()).indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) >= 0)

    }
```